# An API for the HTML Spec itself? Or easy way to scrape the Spec?

Tags: html, ajax, api, w3c

Does anyone know of an API or an easy way to get information about the HTML spec itself? I'd like to create something that listed all of the current current elements and their specific attributes, etc.

The only way I know is if I pulled the source of the spec and manually scraped through it, which would be incredibly tedious.

Please let me know if you know of any easier ways.

Comment: Which HTML spec (HTML 5, XHTML 1.1, etc.)?

Comment: Ideally everything up to HTML5.

Comment: I'm searching the same. Apparently there is no such a thing as a html5 DTD. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053917/where-is-the-html5-document-type-definition
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638366/is-there-an-xhtml-xsd-equivalent-available-for-html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DTD.

Example: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

Comment: I think there is no DTD for html5 :(