# Is there an xhtml.xsd equivalent available for HTML5?

Tags: html, xsd, porting, xml-validation, xulrunner

I am developing an appplication based on Mozilla XULRunner.

I am using the `xhmtl1-strict.xsd` provided by the W3C to fetch the attribute. Now the requirement came to add the `<video>` tag to my application, but my application is not supporting any HTML5 elements or attributes.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Same for DTD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053917/where-is-the-html5-document-type-definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5 does not have a doctype definition or an XML schema definition. This is because, although it shares the same syntax as its predecessor HTML 4, HTML5 itself is neither based on SGML nor XML. It's a markup language in its own right.

If you are looking to implement a browser with HTML5 capabilities using Mozilla technologies, the latest version of the Gecko layout engine supports HTML5. Get the Gecko/XULRunner SDK [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_sdk).

Answer (score 6):

The packages at http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml contain a file addon/config/xhtml/xsd/5.0/xhtml5.xsd which seems to be licensed as open source .

Comment: The XSD of the XMLmind-pack is non-oficial and it have inconsistencies with http://dev.w3.org/html5  , but was a good starting point for me (!), thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [HTML5 DTD](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/contrib/catalogs/html5/html5.dtd) which is used in the XML Catalog of Komodo, which is an XULRunner application. It can also be used in [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog) without being converted to an XSD. In addition, there are [style sheet](http://people.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/dtd/conversions.html) and [regex](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/schema_hack/) based DTD2XSD converters available.

Answer (score 2):

To validate XHTML5, use the schema from v.Nu.

For details, see:

https://github.com/unsoup/validator

Comment: That could be useful in some cases, but it's unfortunate that it's not a full xsd schema - it's based on Relax NG, and so, you can't, for example, use it with all validators, nor use it with tools like xjc which creates JAXB Java Binding Classes, for XHTML5.