# Why can't the <p> tag contain a <div> tag inside it?

Tags: html, xhtml

As far as I know, this is right:

```
<div>
  <p>some words</p>
</div>
```

But this is wrong:

```
<p>
  <div>some words</div>
</p>
```

The first one can pass [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) (XHTML 1.0), but the second can't. I know that nobody will write code like the second one. I just want know why.

And what about other tags' containment relationship?

Comment: Because `<p>` is a block level element, and is (supposed to be) used for displaying text, it won't allow other block level elements inside it, but only inline ones like `<span>` and `<strong>`.

Comment: JamWaffles: That `p` is a block level element has nothing to do with it. `div` is also one and allows other blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li (unflagged): any decent answer to that will answer how to read the HTML spec and thus also answer this.

Comment: Declaring the div's style as inline doesn't work either.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

An authoritative place to look for allowed containment relations is the HTML spec. See, for example, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html. It specifies which elements are block elements and which are inline. For those lists, search for the section marked "HTML content models".

For the P element, it specifies the following, which indicates that P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Comment: I have a habit of avoiding the specs, the most authoritative documents we have for things like this, because they aren't fun to read. +1 for actually reading them, understanding them, and using them to answer questions.

Comment: Is this still valid for HTML 5? The spec linked specifically references HTML 4, and [HTML 5 doesn't have a document type definition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4053917/1157054).

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p). HTML5 has renamed lots of terminology, but "Permitted contents: phrasing content" means the same as the `%inline` bit above. See also Oriol's answer.

Comment: @Stoutie Right with ya, that's why Stack Overflow exists.

Comment: But that's not consistent with div inside div being ok, by this explanation.

Answer (score 74):

In short, it is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

Comment: Ah, this explains why there's a huge space before a div inside a p, because the p actually ends just before the div.

Comment: You *can* place a `div` element inside a `p` *in the DOM*, e.g. `myP.appendChild(myDiv)`. But a HTML parser won't do it.

Comment: Dont do that. You have no idea how that will respond in future browsers. Technology is changing constantly. There may be a dynamic html parser that will make that invalid one day. The goal in web dev is to create things that have the ability to be both desireable and somewhat compatible. If you can bypass what the browser allows, its safe to say you cannot ensure that it will work forever. Just use a span guys... If you need a div, stop using the p tag.

Answer (score 54):

According to HTML5, the [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-model) of [`div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) elements is [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content)

> Most elements that are used in the body of documents and applications are categorized as flow content.

That includes [`p`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements, which [can only be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#contexts-in-which-this-element-can-be-used) where [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content) is expected.

Therefore, `div` elements can contain `p` elements.

---

However, the [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-model) of [`p`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements is [Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content)

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of [phrasing
>   content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content) form [paragraphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraph).

That doesn't include [`div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) elements, which [can only be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#contexts-in-which-this-element-can-be-used) where [flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content) is expected.

Therefore, `p` elements can't contain `div` elements.

Since the [end tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags) of [`p`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements can be omitted when the `p` element is immediately followed by a `div` element (among others), the following

```
<p>
  <div>some words</div>
</p>
```

is parsed as

```
<p></p>
<div>some words</div>
</p>
```

and the last `</p>` is an error.

Comment: But if in CSS if I set div to be inline why it's not respecting that?

Comment: Since CSS values are applied after dom Parsing... 
even if we make `div as inline in CSS` its is no use, as new parsed structure is
```<p>Text</p>
<div>some words</div>
<p></p>```

is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Sanjay Yes, looks like you are right. And moreover, during my observations, if you put <span> inside <p> and then set span's display to "block", it will be rendered as a typical block element without such an effect.

Answer (score 3):

### Look at this example from the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-SPAN)

```html
<!-- Example of data from the client database: -->
<!-- Name: Stephane Boyera, Tel: (212) 555-1212, Email: sb@foo.org -->

<DIV id="client-boyera" class="client">
<P><SPAN class="client-title">Client information:</SPAN>
<TABLE class="client-data">
<TR><TH>Last name:<TD>Boyera</TR>
<TR><TH>First name:<TD>Stephane</TR>
<TR><TH>Tel:<TD>(212) 555-1212</TR>
<TR><TH>Email:<TD>sb@foo.org</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
```

**Did you notice something?** : There was no closing tag of the `<p>` element. a mistake in the specs ? **No**.

#### Tip #1: The closing tag of `<p>` is OPTIONAL

**You may ask**: But then how would a `<p>` element knows where to stop?

From [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-p-tag.html):

> If the closing tag is omitted, it is considered that the end of the paragraph matches with the start of the next block-level element.

*In simple words*: a `<div>` is a block element and its opening tag will cause the parent `<p>` to be closed, thus `<div>` can never be nested inside `<p>`.

**BUT what about the inverse situation ? you may ask**

well ...

### Tip #2: The closing tag of the `<div>` element is REQUIRED

According to O’Reilly HTML and XHTML Pocket Reference, Fourth Edition (page 50)

> `<div> . . . </div>`
> Start/End Tags
> Required/Required

That is, the `<div>` element's end will only be determined by its closing tag `</div>` hence a `<p>` element inside is will NOT break it.

Answer (score -1):

After the X HTML, the conventions has been changed, and now it's a mixture of conventions of XML and HTML, so that is why the second approach is wrong and the W3C validator accepts the things correct that are according to the standards and conventions.

Comment: XHTML didn't change much. The p element has **never** been allowed to contain a div element.

Answer (score -7):

Because the `div` tag has higher precedence than the `p` tag. The `p` tag represents a paragraph tag whereas the `div` tag represents a document tag.

You can write many paragraphs in a document tag, but you can't write a document in a paragraph. The same as a DOC file.

Comment: Actually, it's division. Otherwise it'd be `<doc>` :D

Comment: Precedence is not a concept that applies to html elements, and div represents a division, as @KyleSevenoaks says :)

Comment: What is a DOC file? A [Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) file?