# Foreach Loop Nesting Isn't Working

Tags: php, html, foreach, nested

So I'm working on a form, and I'm using PHP to pull an array of contacts out of a database. As the result is an array, I'm using a foreach loop to echo the contacts and move on. Here is my code:

```
    <p class='contact-list'>
      <?php

        foreach( $contacts as $contact ){
            echo "<p><input type='radio' name='contact' id='contact-{$contact['id']}' value='{$contact['id']}'/>";
            echo " {$contact['name']}</p>";
        }

      ?>
    </p>
```

I'm doing this because I want each of the contacts to be placed as a child to the .contact-list, and when the page renders, the source seems like it should be:

```
<p class='contact-list'>
    <p><input type='radio' ...
    </p>
    <p><input type='radio' ...
    </p>
</p>
```

That's not how it is. Instead of being children to the .contact-list, each contact is a sibling to it, and I'm wondering why this is happening.

The source from the page after it's rendered is this:

```
<p class='contact-list'></p>
<p><input type='radio' name=''...
</p>
<p><input type='radio' name=''...
</p>
```

Can anyone explain why the Paragraph tag is closing before the foreach loop runs?

**Update:**

I decided to use a div instead of a paragraph, and then nesting worked right, so I'm assuming that this is a trait of the paragraph tag. That said, I'm still interested in finding out *why* the paragraph tag does this.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: The accepted answer tells me exactly what is going on! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `p` is a block element which can contain only inline elements. But you put other `p`-elements in it. Use `span` instead the `p`s and this should work as you expect

Comment: +1.  Another alternative is to make the contact-list a div element.

Comment: @kuh-chan: Why can't the Paragraph tag take other block level elements? I would've thought that since both div and p were block-level, they both would work.

Comment: @Goldentoa11: because the `p` is explicit defined for texts - and texts only contain inline elements. That's what I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach( $contacts as $contact ){
        echo "<span><input type='radio' name='contact' id='contact-{$contact['id']}' value='{$contact['id']}'/>{$contact['name']} </span>";
    }
```

Comment: I was using the p tag because it automatically goes to a new line after it's closed.

Comment: you can replace span with div. That will give you new line every time.

Comment: div is also block and does the same thing as `<p>`... 
Use `<br>` to do the new line