# jQuery selector, IE <P><FORM> selector behavior

Tags: selector, jquery

If your prepend a FORM element with a P element, elements below the DIV in the example will not be selected!

```
<P><FORM id=f ...
<INPUT ...>
<DIV><INPUT (this element is not selectable)
</DIV>
</FORM>
```

No `$('#f INPUT').events` will happen in IE for the second input above
Try the testcase at: http://jsfiddle.net/jorese/Bzc7M/

In IE you will receive an alert=3, remove the P element in front of the FORM element and you get the expected alert=5. In Chrome|FF you get alert=5 as expected.

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: 1. Try using valid HTML (e.g. where's the closing `<p>` TAG? 2. Quote your tag attribute values.

Comment: I believed the P endtag was optional, see [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P). For simple attribute values quotes are optional as well see [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is **not valid**, it contains a few errors, the reason why some browsers render it is that they *tolerate invalid code* to some extent by trying to guess what the developer originally wanted to write.

The `div` element can be used to group almost any elements together. Indeed, it can contain almost any other element, **unlike `p`, which can only contain inline elements**.

Use `div` instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/mshMX/

Sitepoint reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/p

W3 reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

A former StackOverflow question about the same problem: [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, so much for the optional end tag... [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P)