# How to get all text from all tags in one array?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I need to create an array which contains all text from a page without jQuery. This is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>
        <div>What are you doing?</div>
        <div>Fine, and you?</div>
    </p>
    <a href="http://google.com">Thank you!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what i want to get

```
text[1] = "Hello world!";
text[2] = "Hello!";
text[3] = "What are you doing?";
text[4] = "Fine, and you?";
text[5] = "Thank you!";
```

Here is what i have tried but seems to not work correctly in my browser:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
console.log(elements);
```

PS. I need to use document.getElementsByTagName('*'); and exclude "script" and "style".

Comment: var full_text = '';
$(':not(#anything)').each(function(index, element) {
  var text = $(element).text();
  full_text.push(text);
}

Comment: Seems to return all the elements for me in Chrome, and FF: http://jsfiddle.net/7JJdn/

Comment: thank you, but i can`t use jQuery ..

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: it is working on jsFiddle, but not in my project .. try to create it local

Comment: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20130718-iw1f-53kb.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var array = [];

    var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var current = elements[i];
        if(current.children.length === 0 && current.textContent.replace(/ |\n/g,'') !== '') {
           // Check the element has no children && that it is not empty
           array.push(current.textContent);
        }
    }
```

You could do something like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhHZG/1)

result = `["What are you doing?", "Fine, and you?"]`

or you could use `document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('*');`

Also make sure your code is inside this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

   /// Code...
});
```

If it's just the title you need, you may aswell do this

```
array.push(document.title);
```

Saves looping through scripts & styles

Comment: TypeError: document.body is null

var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

Comment: @Connor right - on the other hand, `document.body.textContent` is pretty much exactly what the OP wants (probably).

Comment: Yeah you need to do it in a domReady jsfiddle

Comment: @Connor Your answer is good, but i need also the title to have in my array ... so i need document.getElementsByTagName("*") and exclude script tag as example.

Comment: @Connor oh OK, sorry; I read your answer in haste and missed that.

Comment: @smotru if i have put in the answer you can also use `document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('*');`

Comment: Hmm, "document.title" would be an option, but i want the script to use document.getElementsByTagName(*); is there any method ? if so please help me with excluding script and style.. thank you

Comment: This helped me to finish my work! Thank you. I used this to filter: if (current.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script' && current.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'style')

Answer (score 2):

If you want the contents of the entire page, you should be able to use

```
var allText = document.body.textContent;
```

In Internet Explorer before IE9, there was the property `innerText` which is similar but not identical.  The [MDN page about `textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) has more detail.

Now one problem here is that `textContent` will get you the content of any `<style>` or `<script>` tags, which may or may not be what you want.  If you don't want that, you could use something like this:

```
function getText(startingPoint) {
  var text = "";
  function gt(start) {
    if (start.nodeType === 3)
      text += start.nodeValue;
    else if (start.nodeType === 1)
      if (start.tagName != "SCRIPT" && start.tagName != "STYLE")
        for (var i = 0; i < start.childNodes.length; ++i)
          gt(start.childNodes[i]);
  }
  gt(startingPoint);
  return text;
}
```

Then:

```
var allText = getText(document.body);
```

**Note:** this (or `document.body.innerText`) will get you all the text, but in a depth-first order. Getting all the text from a page in the order that a human actually sees it once the page is rendered is a *much* more difficult problem, because it'd require the code to understand the visual effects (and visual semantics!) of the layout as dictated by CSS (etc).

*edit* — if you want the text "stored into an array", I suppose on a node-by-node basis (?), you'd simply substitute array appends for the string concatenation in the above:

```
function getTextArray(startingPoint) {
  var text = [];
  function gt(start) {
    if (start.nodeType === 3)
      text.push(start.nodeValue);
    else if (start.nodeType === 1)
      if (start.tagName != "SCRIPT" && start.tagName != "STYLE")
        for (var i = 0; i < start.childNodes.length; ++i)
          gt(start.childNodes[i]);
  }
  gt(startingPoint);
  return text;
}
```

Comment: Yes that gat all text (except title), but it is not storred into an array.

Comment: well @smotru if you don't know how to store something into a array then your on the wrong page. I'm sure it's possible to look through other answers to see how they are storing it

Comment: @Connor i know to store something into an array but i can`t understand Pointy`s script .. little comments should help ..

Comment: @smotru the script has been updated - it's just a recursive traverse of the DOM.

Comment: I see and thank you for your help, but it`s working only with document.body

Comment: Your answer helped me to finish my work, but Connor`s script was more clean and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a one line solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx7KH/)):

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s*<[^>]*>\s*$|>\s*</g,'').split(/<[^>]*>/g)
```

This may fail if there are complicated scripts in the `body`, though, and I know that parsing HTML with regular expressions [is not a very clever idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but for simple cases or for demo purposes it still can be suitable, can't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Hello world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <p>
                    <div>What are you doing?</div>
                    <div>Fine, 
                        <span> and you? </span>
                    </div>
            </p>
            <a href="http://google.com">Thank you!</a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function getLeafNodesOfHTMLTree(root) {
                    if (root.nodeType == 3) {
                        return [root];
                    } else {
                        var all = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++) {
                            var ret2 = getLeafNodesOfHTMLTree(root.childNodes[i]);
                            all = all.concat(ret2);
                        }
                        return all;
                    }
                }
                var allnodes = getLeafNodesOfHTMLTree(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
                console.log(allnodes);
                 //in modern browsers that surport array filter and map
                allnodes = allnodes.filter(function (node) {
                    return node && node.nodeValue && node.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
                });
                allnodes = allnodes.map(function (node) {
                    return node.nodeValue
                })
                 console.log(allnodes);
            </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The "childNodes" of an element are just the immediate children.

Comment: by the way , P tag can not contains DIV tag see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: i know, it`s just an example .. my script should work on not w3 validated pages

Answer (score 0):

Walk the DOM tree, get all the text nodes, get the nodeValue of the text node.

```
var result = [];
var itr = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null, // no filter
    false);
while(itr.nextNode()) {
    if(itr.currentNode.nodeValue != "")
        result.push(itr.currentNode.nodeValue);
}
alert(result);
```

Alternate method: Split on the HTML tag's textContent.

```
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].textContent.split("\n");
for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
    if(result[i] == "")
        result.splice(i, 1);
alert(result);
```

Comment: @Connor - createTreeWalker has sketchy support in older versions of IE.