# How to built a text array of the document content with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi how can I extract the text of an document as an array within javascript.
It´s easy to get the innerHTML, but I do not get the text before and after the div for example.
This should be the output:

```
[0]=before div
[1]=innerHTML
[2]=aferHTML
[3]=before div2
[4]=innerHTML2
[5]=aferHTML2
```

Of the following document:

```
<html><head>
<body>
before div  <div>innerHTML  </div>aferHTML
before div2 <div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2
</body></html>
```

I found this link, but it does not get the text before and after the elements as well:
[How to get all text from all tags in one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727977/how-to-get-all-text-from-all-tags-in-one-array)

Answer (score 0):

You scenario is not clear. Could you please elaborate more the specific reason.

However if you want to get text from all elements in a document, kindly review this thread -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346709/loop-through-html-tags-in-string-and-add-inner-text-to-array).

Comment: Thanks I try again. 

How do I make a loop that I also get this content:

<body> before div  <div>


I mean the text above BEFORE DIV.
This code only catches the content between tags:
  var array = [];

    var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var current = elements[i];
        if(current.children.length === 0 && current.textContent.replace(/ |\n/g,'') !== '') {
           // Check the element has no children && that it is not empty
           array.push(current.textContent);
        }
    }

Comment: This not an answer @Wajid Use the comment section for discussions like these.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee because of less reputation, I can't comment. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `childNodes` property you can achieve this. But for `afterHtml` and `before div2`, you need to do some extra work because they are part of the same text node.

Please take a look at the snippet below. You can remove the last element of the array manually.

```js
const arr = [];
document.body.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    arr.push(node.textContent.trim());
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<body>
    before div <div>innerHTML </div>aferHTML
    before div2 <div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's mine.

As you can see, I wrapped your HTML inside a div with a class name `content`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        before div  <div>innerHTML  </div>aferHTML
before div2 <div>innerHTML2 </div>aferHTML2
    </div>
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.querySelector('.content').children;

    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < body.length ; i++) {

        var before = body[i].previousSibling.nodeValue.trim();
        var inner = body[i].innerHTML;
        var after = body[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();

        if (before && i == 0) list.push(before); //prevent duplication and empty value

        list.push(inner);
        
        if(after) list.push(after); //prevent empty value

    }

    console.log(list); //output

</script>
```

in innerHTML, you could split the string using `inner.split(" ")` if you like.

Comment: thanks the solution works, but now I need to do it for multiple level Hirachie not just with a childs. The childs will also have children,... and so on. How can I do that?