# Div is pushed out of <p>

Tags: html

So my div is being pushed out of my

```
$html = '
<p>
    <a href="*link*?id='.$newsr["topic_id"].'" title="'.$newsr["topic_subject"].'">'.$newsr["topic_subject"].'</a><div style="float:right;">'.$newsr["topic_date"].'</div>
</p>';
echo $html;
```

with as result :

```
<p>
    <a href="*link*?id=21" title="GHBJN">GHBJN</a>
</p>
<div style="float:right;">2013-07-18 17:05:09</div>
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<p>` tag can only contain phrasing content ([see W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/p.html#p)).

The `<div>` element on the other hand is a block element, which implicitly closes any open paragraphs tags as defined in the standard.

> **A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by** an address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, **div**, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

This is exactly, what is applying here.

Comment: I believe it's allowed in html5

Comment: @arnaud576875 Sure it is allowed. But the defined behavior may differ from what is expected (by an inexperienced user).

Comment: Care to explain why ?

Comment: @arnaud576875 If you do not know the behavior concerning implicit closing tags, you could assume, that the `<div>` should be contained within the `<p>` and hence, e.g., the appropriate styling is applied. The defined behavior, however, results in different structures like shown by OP.

Answer (score 1):

One one does not simply put `<div>` element in `<p>` element.

edit: for more explanation please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it).

Comment: I'd +1 this 1000x hahahah. `One does not simply walk into Mordor` reference ftw.