# Jquery html() method not working if we place a div inside a p tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML:

```
  <div class="accor">
  </div>
  <div class="accordionContentTwoCol">
   <p class="noEdit">
     <div>   name : </div>
  </p>
 <div>
```

I need to find html content of `accordionContentTwoCol` div (i have access only to `accor`).
If i try to print html inside accordionContentTwoCol div like this:

```
alert("html inside accordionContentTwoCol :"+$('.accor').next().html());
```

It gives output like this:
[image]

Though HTML inside `accordionContentTwoCol` is:

```
<p class="noEdit">
         <div>   name : </div>
</p>
```

why that happens?

Comment: Because it's invalid and the browser moves the div to the next valid position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An authoritative place to look for allowed containment relations is the HTML spec. See, for example, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html. It specifies which elements are block elements and which are inline. For those lists, search for the section marked "HTML content models".

For the P element, it specifies the following, which indicates that P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

[Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Answer (score 1):

The markup you use is wrong. The `<div>` cannot be nested with `<p>` Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<div style="display: inline">
```

Otherwise, use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML 4.01 specification section 9.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

The **P element** represents a paragraph. It cannot contain [block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline) (including **P itself**).