# How to automatically change words and color in a phrase with css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a dynamic phrase like doyouimpress.com

The code I use for HTML is: [Source](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations/)

```
<section class="rw-wrapper">
     <h1 class="rw-sentence">
     Phrase one             
         <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
        <span>Word 1</span>
        <span>Word 2</span>
        <span>Word 3</span>
        </div>
    </h1>
</section>
<h2 class="rw-sentence-IE">Phrase for internet explorer</h2>
```

The code I use for CSS is: (I have errors when pasting the CSS here, please see Source.)

With this code the words automatically change but the phrase does not change position when the words are long or short.

What I do wrong and how can I get a similar effect to: doyouimpress.com

Comment: Just a note, `div` is **not** allowed as child of `h1`.

Comment: a topic about @Vucko [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it).

Comment: Read, try, try again and if it's fail... ask. You say `...Phrase for internet explorer`... and in the FIRST comment of your `SOURCE article` says that don't work in IE. Author (ML) also set a note *`"Please note: the result of this tutorial will only work as intended in browsers that support CSS animations."`*. So... In which browser/version is not working for you? And don't forget @Vucko's comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CSS is left-aligning the sentence that gets changed with:

```
text-align: left;
```

If you change that to

```
 text-align: center;
```

You might find that the sentence/phrase changes position when it's a different word.