# jQuery .html() method closing <p> tag issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading in some html via ajax and inserting it into the DOM. Here is the part of the recieved data, outputted into the console:

```
<div class="devices">
    <h3> Devices </h3>
    <p> 
        <div class="device-icon android-icon"></div>
        <div class="device-icon iphone-icon"></div>
        <div class="device-icon blackberry-icon"></div>
    </p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `p` tags are arranged fine. However, when I insert the data into the dom with jQuery's `html()` method, this is how it's actually appended:

```
<div class="devices">
    <h3> Devices </h3>
    <p></p>
        <div class="device-icon android-icon"></div>
        <div class="device-icon iphone-icon"></div>
        <div class="device-icon blackberry-icon"></div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

What's going on with the p tags?

Comment: @Blazemonger I'd say that that question is closely-related, but the original poster asked this in the context of jQuery not working as expected. I'm not convinced that this is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why the javascript parser is doing this is actually because `<p>` tags are not allowed to include `<div>` tags within the HTML spec. Please refer to the html specification and this question ([Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)).

Comment: *"The reason why jquery is doing this"* -> *"The reason **the browser** is doing this"*

Comment: Can't believe I'm only finding out about this now! You learn something new every day. Thank you.

Comment: @styke Accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks. :)