# Creating a <div> inside a <p> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a div inside a p with a click function. But it seems not to close my p element. Apparently after reading [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p), it seems that if the p element is immediately followed by a div in this case it doesn't require a closing tag at the end.

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="content-list"><ul class="information"> </ul></div>
```

I'm going to append to the  with this function:

```
var $contentHandler = $(".content-list");
var $mainHandler = $(".main");
var $infoHandler = $(".information");
var circleCounter = 1;



$mainHandler.click(function() {
    var htmlString = "<li class='" + circleCounter + "'> <p class='circle-color'> var   color = <div class='circle-color-input' contentEditable autocorrect='off'> type a color</div> ; </p> <p class='circle-radius'> </p> <p class='circle'> </p> </li>"
    $infoHandler.append(htmlString);
    circleCounter++;


});
```

Here is the code for that

http://jsfiddle.net/mauricioSanchez/tJkex/

Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: You quite simply *cannot* have a div inside a p. It just doesn't work. You can use a span instead and make it display as a block if needed.

Comment: var   color =  before the <div ... why???

Comment: P is a block level element, and as such shouldn't contain other block level elements.

Comment: @C-link I'm just simulating if I were appending code, don't pay attention to that

Comment: @flauntster your statement is wrong, why block level cannot contain block level element div is block level and and p is block level then <div><p></p></div> about what do you think ?

Comment: @BoltClock I changed it for a span and it works, thank you!

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer so your question won't remain unanswered.

Comment: Everiting is posible if you will just look at this http://jsfiddle.net/tJkex/2/

Comment: @C-link, yeh you are correct there, cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You quite simply *cannot* have a `div` inside a `p`, because the only kind of content allowed in a `p` element is phrasing content (as stated in the document you've read), which usually means inline elements. That's why having a `div` (or any other flow element such as `ul` or `figure`) immediately following an unclosed `p` will implicitly close that `p` and be created as a sibling, not a child, in the DOM.

You can use a `span` instead and make it display as a block if needed:

```
var htmlString = "<li class='" + circleCounter + "'> <p class='circle-color'> var   color = <span class='circle-color-input' contentEditable autocorrect='off'> type a color</span> ; </p> <p class='circle-radius'> </p> <p class='circle'> </p> </li>"
```

Answer (score 2):

`div` is not allowed to be inside `p`, see 
[Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

The browser think you forgot to enclose the `p` tag, so it implicitly adds a closing tag before `div`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the css property overflow:scroll ?