# Specific div positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a header for a webpage that looks like this:

[image: header]

and here's the code I'm trying so far:

**HTML**

```
<header id="top-section">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="float-left">
          <a href="../Home/Index"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg" alt="SustIMS" width="50%" height="50%" /></a>
      </div>
      <p class="user-info">
          <div class="user-info">
          Welcome Jon
          </div>
      <div class="float-right">
          <a href="Index">
          <img class="toolbar-icons" alt="Home" src="http://htiins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/home-icon.png" /></a>
      </div>
      </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1); 
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}


#top-section
{
    border: 4px solid blue;
    height: 120px;

}


.user-info
{
    float: right;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border: 2px solid green;

}

.toolbar-icons
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VR85/).

I've set borders in different colors to better understand the divs positioning.

How can I achieve something like the image above?

Thanks

*EDIT**

Maybe this explains better what I'm looking for: here's how it should look like:

[image: example]

Thanks for some great answers so far!

Comment: Just added the example fiddle to the question

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/M7633/).

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/S4Nqj/

Comment: Which is **the image** and which are **the icons**? what about the expected size, spacing etc of icons..?

Comment: @TJ check the edit on the question. I can manipulate the spacing with margin, padding, etc., but the positioning of the things is my issue here. The image is set inside the content wrapper on the left and the user info and icons are on the right: user info on top of the icons

Comment: Just use two divs with 50% width and keep text-align left and right respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
<p class="user-info">
<div class="user-info">
      Welcome Jon
</div>
```

into our float-right div and give header the css style of

```
header{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
}
```

to end up with this result.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9Zjx/

Comment: `DIV` inside `P` ? no : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: @AurélienGrimpard The Div isn't inside the P tag. To be honest, thanks, I didn't notice that the p tag wasn't closed but if you read defau1t's answer in the link you posted you'll see the p tag is automatically closed by the div element anyway.

Comment: Thanks @judgeja! That made it for me, just had to tweak it a bit with the actual images I'm using

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what dimensions you want to work with and whether this is supposed to be responsive, e.g. stacked on mobile devices, but this should help you get closer to what you want. I cleaned up the `code` a bit ...

**http://jsfiddle.net/7VR85/2/**

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code like below. Changing some tag and adding some style property to your fiddle.

```
  <header id="top-section">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="float-left">
      <a href="../Home/Index"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg" alt="SustIMS" width="50%" height="50%" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="float-right">
      <div class="user-info">
      Welcome Jona  </div>

      <a href="Index">
      <img class="toolbar-icons" alt="Home" src="http://htiins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/home-icon.png" /></a>

  </div>     
</div>    
</header>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5at3/)