# Python3, BeautifulSoup dropping a paragraph tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

If have the following chunk of html:

```
chunk = '<p>BLA bla bla html... <div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div></p>'
```

When I do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(chunk)
```

The chunk turns into this:

```
>>> soup
<html><body><p>BLA bla bla html... </p><div>Copyright 2014 Someone</div></body></html>
```

The paragraph tag gets closed early and the div is pulled outside of it.

I was surprised by this. Is this expected behavior for BeautifulSoup and if so, can anyone explain why it's doing this?

**EDIT:** Just to note, I realize that this html is invalid, but I didn't realize BeautifulSoup would edit invalid html to this degree. [Here's a related SO question on invalid HTML (div instead a p tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML you presented is not a valid well-formed one. In this case, as stated in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful
>   Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter.
>   One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a
>   data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>
> But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will
>   give different results.

So, the behavior really [depends on the underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) used by `BeautifulSoup`. And, since you haven't specified it explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` chooses it [according to the ranking](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

This is what different parsers tries to do with the html you have provided:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> chunk = '<p>BLA bla bla html... <div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div></p>'

# html.parser
>>> BeautifulSoup(chunk, 'html.parser')
<p>BLA bla bla html... <div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div></p> 

# html5lib
>>> BeautifulSoup(chunk, 'html5lib')
<html><head></head><body><p>BLA bla bla html... </p><div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div><p></p></body></html>

# lxml
>>> BeautifulSoup(chunk, 'lxml')
<html><body><p>BLA bla bla html... </p><div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div></body></html>

# xml
>>> BeautifulSoup(chunk, 'xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p>BLA bla bla html... <div>Copyright 2014 NPR</div></p>
```

According to the output, you have `lxml` installed in this particular python environment, and `BeautifulSoup` uses it as an underlying parser since you haven't specified it explicitly.

Comment: Followup: this is a really nicely written response and I used the information in it today to solve a problem I've had for a few days. Thanks again!