# Not able to propagate event listener (submit for form) for element generated by(later) javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code like -

```
<div class = "setup_eda_class" id = "Setup_eda">
<p>
<a> <span id="calendar_eda_form_top_x"> x </span> </a>
<br> </br>
<div id="insert_calendar_eda_form"> </div>
</p>
</div>
```

The div 'insert_calendar_eda_form' is inserted initially.

Javascript code

```js
    calendar_eda_add_form = function (clicked_id, arraylength){
    htmlstr = "";
 htmlstr += '<a> Add Events for - </a>' ;
 htmlstr += '<form id="calendar_eda_add_form" action="/setupaddcalendarevent" method="POST">'
 htmlstr += '<label for="start_date">Start Date</label>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="text" name="start_date" />'
 htmlstr += '<label for="end_date">End Date</label>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="text" name="end_date" />'
 htmlstr += '<br> </br>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="submit" value="Add Event" />'
 htmlstr += '</form>'
 $("#insert_calendar_eda_form").html(htmlstr);
```

The form 'calendar_eda_add_form' html is created dynamically by Javascript.

HTML code for event listener

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#insert_calendar_eda_form').on('submit', 'calendar_eda_add_form', function(event){
 alert ('clicked add event');
 event.preventDefault();
 somefunction();
 });
 });
```

Calendar_eda_add_form is generated dynamically by JS. I am trying to propagate the "submit" event, but does not seem to work. Can you please help?

Comment: you have to delegate events for future elements that don't exist at runtime  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: The Server side Python code for /setupaddcalendarevent gets executed. But I am expecting Javascript to prevent this action and execute the somefunction()

Comment: my answer should accomplish that

Comment: @charlietfl Is there any reason to do it this way rather than doing $('#calendar_eda_add_form').on('submit',function(event)?

Comment: @DelightedD0D you can use that BUT only after the form exists. So you could insert the form and then run that code

Comment: How many times are inserting the form into the DOM?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, missed that

Comment: @charlietfl - Any ideas on why the delegation of events is not working?

Comment: Any errors in the console? And you're sure that `<div id="insert_calendar_eda_form"> </div>` exists at DOM ready?

Comment: bind it to the document... `$(document).on('submit','#calendar_eda_add_form...`

Comment: Your HTML is not valid **P can only contain inline elements** - `<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`

Comment: Console shows an error

$('#insert_calendar_eda_form').on('click', 'calendar_eda_add_form', function(event){

<exception>: TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Missing the hash tag on the selector inside the .on()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insert_calendar_eda_form').on('submit', '#calendar_eda_add_form', function(event){
    alert ('clicked add event');
    event.preventDefault();
    somefunction();
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing it working http://jsfiddle.net/ja3kaa4b/ - are you seeing any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Still doesn't work. The Python code for /setupaddcalendarevent gets executed.

Comment: Is there any reason to do it this way rather than doing `$('#calendar_eda_add_form').on('submit',function(event)`?

Comment: calendar_eda_add_form is dynamically generated by JS after the document is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing the effects of duplicate IDs. In the function `calendar_eda_add_form` change the ID of the form to a class and use the following code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insert_calendar_eda_form').on('submit', '.calendar_eda_add_form', function(event){
        alert ('clicked add event');
        event.preventDefault();
        somefunction();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Per the comments under the question, the above is unlikely as the form is added to the DOM only once. However, the HTML being used is not valid:

```
<div class = "setup_eda_class" id = "Setup_eda">
<p>
<a> <span id="calendar_eda_form_top_x"> x </span> </a>
<br> </br>
<div id="insert_calendar_eda_form"> </div>
</p>
</div>
```

Per the HTML spec **P elements can only contain inline elements**; **div - the target div - is not an inline element.**

- [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html

Comment: given that the other answers dont seem to be helping the OP i'd say this is very likely

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```js
calendar_eda_add_form = function (clicked_id, arraylength){
    htmlstr = "";
 htmlstr += '<a> Add Events for - </a>' ;
 htmlstr += '<form id="calendar_eda_add_form" action="/setupaddcalendarevent" method="POST">'
 htmlstr += '<label for="start_date">Start Date</label>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="text" name="start_date" />'
 htmlstr += '<label for="end_date">End Date</label>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="text" name="end_date" />'
 htmlstr += '<br> </br>'
 htmlstr += '<input type="submit" value="Add Event" />'
 htmlstr += '</form>'
    
    return htmlstr;
   // in your code I dont see where you ever do anything with `htmlstr `. 
   // Since you made `calendar_eda_add_form` a function, I'm assuming you meant to return `htmlstr`
   // and insert the created html into your `insert_calendar_eda_form` div
   // im assuming you have a reason for `clicked_id, arraylength` here but not sure what they are for
 }   







$(document).ready(function(){
   //change this line to add the `#` and bind to `document`
 $(document).on('submit','#calendar_eda_add_form',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    somefunction();
 });
  
  //put here to simulate adding form later
  $('#create').click(function(){
      
       //insert the created html into your `insert_calendar_eda_form` div
       $('#insert_calendar_eda_form').html(calendar_eda_add_form);
    });
  
});




function somefunction(){
  
  alert ('clicked add event');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="create" value="create form"/>
<div class = "setup_eda_class" id = "Setup_eda">
<p>
<a> <span id="calendar_eda_form_top_x"> x </span> </a>
<br> </br>
<div id="insert_calendar_eda_form"> </div>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: $("#insert_calendar_eda_form").html(htmlstr);
 is already in html code. Have just updated my question.

Comment: gotcha, but doing the above, it's still posting the form and not preventing it?

Comment: Yes. It is still posting the form not preventing it @DelightedD0D . Per your suggestion, I looked at the console it is throwing up an error TypeError: undefined is not a function message: "undefined is not a function

Comment: in your actual code, in the `$(document).on` function, do you call anything before `event.preventDefault();` ? Also, are you sure you added the `#` at the front of `#calendar_eda_add_form` ?