# HTML5 output explanation

Tags: html

These two simplified HTML5 codes gets the same result:

code #1:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

--

code #2:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    test1
</body>
</html>
```

====

The output is the same in both cases, the screen prints the word "test1", so what the use of the tag `<p>` ? how does the browser understand the two codes? please note that the file code is .html extension

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529390/ok-to-have-text-in-div-without-paragraph-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OK to have text in div without paragraph tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529390/ok-to-have-text-in-div-without-paragraph-tag)

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag stands for *paragraph*, which is used for text, and you can read more about it at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

If you take a a good look you'll see the output is not the same, the `p` is slightly far down the page because it has a default margin set, which for example a `div` does not.

The browser parse through the code/markup and render the content in each tag accordingly to that particular tags default layout settings.