# Should a phrase or a single word be in a paragraph tag assuming it shouldn't be in a header or a list item, etc?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

My website has a card that has a photo. Under the photo is a date (just a year number YYYY form). Under that is a heading on a single line. Under that is a paragraph.

Should this date be in a paragraph tag? If not, what should it be in?

According to Kevin Powells' video "The most common HTML mistake // The incorrect use of HTML heading levels", it shouldn't be in a heading tag. That video claims that heading's should be used to outline a hierarchical table of contents for your website, but my date really shouldn't be the name of a section of my website.

Edit: Outside of my specific example though (which I now know should use a  element, should a single word or phrase never be in a <div>?

Comment: Inserting link to link these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529390/ok-to-have-text-in-div-without-paragraph-tag

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`<time>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) and include the
`datetime` attribute.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @RamPrakash No. It is an answer to the question that solves the issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34667879)

Comment: @Kristian The essential part of the answer to his question, "Should this date be in a paragraph tag?" is to consider using the `<time>` element which is a complete answer unto itself. The link is only for information about its usage but that's not part of the question.