# rails - haml child elements render outside parent element

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render the following line of code in haml

```
%p.article-body
  lorem
  = "<div>ipsum</div>".html_safe
```

I intend it to render as

```
<p class="article-body">
  lorem
  <div>ipsum</div>
</p>
```

But instead it renders as

```
<p class="article-body">
  lorem
</p>
<div>ipsum</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? It only happens to those lines with call to html_safe. Otherwise, the contents will render inside the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> %p.article-body= "lorem".html_safe

This is wrong syntax. As `<p>` tag not allowed to contain `<div>` tag.

**[Why `<p>` tag can't contain `<div>` tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)**

Try `<div>` tag(by removing `%p`) instead `<p>` like this:

```
.article-body
  = "<div>lorem</div>".html_safe
```

**OR**

```
.article-body
  != "<div>lorem</div>"  # if you not wanted to use .html_safe
```

plz check this for more details about **[!=](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html)** :

For more Info / Learn HAML structure refer below links:

- http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/#formatting
- http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html
- http://haml.info/tutorial.html

I hope this may helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'm really new to haml. I tried the indentation fix but the lines with html_safe call still renders outside the parent element. It works for those without the html_safe.

Comment: @MartinVerdejo : try `!= "<div>lorem</div>"`  without html_safe and let me know so I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: still no luck using the `!= "<div>lorem</div>"`

Comment: Yeah! Firgured it out as well. Thanks will accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As HAML is indentation sensitive markup, you need to have proper indentation. Try this:

```
%p.article-body
  = "<div>lorem</div>".html_safe
```

Comment: I tried this but the line with `html_safe` call still renders outside the parent element. It works for those without the `html_safe`.

Answer (score 0):

check your indentation. Please change the code like this

```
%p.article-body
  %div lorem
```

Comment: I am actually calling html_safe on a field so the contents of `%p.article-body` will have to be dynamic. I do not plan to hard code the div tag. I tried the indentation but again, those with `html_safe` get rendered outside the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

`%p.article-body`

`%div lorem.html_safe`