# Using <div> tag inside php

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress 4.1.2

I have this bit of php that displays the list of tags to the left of a small image:

```
<p align="right"><?php
the_tags( '&#160; ', ' • ', '<a href="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/faq/lessons-by-level/"><img src="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/graphics/icon-files.png" alt="Lawless French Files" width="20" height="30" align="right" hspace="10" border="0"></a>' );
?></p>
```

I want to replace the img with a sprite:

```
<div id="icon-files" style="float:right; height:30px; width:20px margin:10px" alt="Lawless French Files"></div>
```

So this is the code I'm using:

```
<?php the_tags( '&#160; ', ' • ', '<a href="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/faq/lessons-by-level/"><div id="icon-files" style="float:right; height:30px; width:20px margin:10px" alt="Lawless French Files"></div></a>' ); ?>
```

But it doesn't work - the image goes down to the next line instead of staying to the right of the tags.

Is there some trick to using div tags inside of php? You can see it in action at https://www.lawlessfrench.com

Comment: How is your code for the replacement of img by div ?

Comment: I'm just putting the div code where the img code is:

`<?php
the_tags( '&#160; ', ' • ', '<a href="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/faq/lessons-by-level/"><div id="icon-files" style="float:right; height:30px; width:20px margin:10px" alt="Lawless French Files"></div></a>' );
?>`

Comment: Your code source is not good ? (with " view-source:" before url)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Try in your browser "view-source:" + your domain name. And check the code source. It is not good ? What is the exact difference between what you have and what  you want ?

Comment: I've already done that - as I explained, the code is somehow different in view source than what I actually used on the site. I have `<a href ...><div ...></div></a>` and it's being changed to `<a href ...></a><div ...></div>`. I can see that in the source code, but it doesn't help me figure out why and how that change is occurring.

Comment: You should say that you are using wordpress, and use wordpress tag. Version may help too.

Comment: Try this in your browser    `view-source:https://www.lawlessfrench.com/` I see : `<a href ...><div ...></div></a>` in the source code. `<a href="https://www.lawlessfrench.com/faq/lessons-by-level/"><div id="icon-files" style="float:right; height:30px; width:20px margin:10px" alt="Lawless French Files"></div></a>` . This is not what you want ?

Comment: Using an `id` inside a loop will generate incorrect html. You shouldn't repeat an id on the same page. Try using a `class` instead.

Comment: Yes, that is what I typed and that is what I see when I view source that way. However, it's not working properly. If you look at the live site, the tags at the end of each post are right-aligned, and the icon follows on the next line. But they are supposed to be side by side.

Comment: Please, post the updated code for `the_tag()` that you are using. I mean, the call with the new params you are passing

Comment: Added to my original question @Choma

Comment: Did you try using a `span` tag, instead of a `div`?

Comment: You can mark my answer good by checking the green check.

Comment: Choma's suggestion of `span` rather than `div` is what worked.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, anyway... avoid using the same id more than once, instead use classes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this in your url :

[view-source:https://www.lawlessfrench.com/](http://view-source:https://www.lawlessfrench.com/)

The code source is good :

```
 <a href ...><div ...></div></a>
```

When you remove `<p>` tag around that works.

`<div>` tag in a `<p>` tag doesn't work correctly.

View here :

[Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

> This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, >which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P >itself)."

and :

> the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

Just remove `<p>` tag.

Or use `<span>` tag instead of `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "p" for your tag P will break into new line,insted use div.