# Jquery on focus show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the input, it shows the div on both fields. I want the div to appear on the selected input only.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/a5secarf/)**

```
$('.example').focus(function() {
    $('div.tip').show();
    $(document).bind('focusin.tip click.tip',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.tip, .example').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.tip');
        $('div.tip').fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
$('div.tip').hide();
```

Comment: Validation is very repetitive and it is not important to be different. There many many javascript validation libraries already written, I would suggest you pick one and learn how to use it good. This way you can easilly add validation to every page you develop, instead of wasting time writing validation scripts EVERY time you write one page. Check this out: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/the-ten-best-javascript-libraries-for-form-validation-and-formatting pick where you spend your time developing, dont rewrite code when you have so many already available to you.

Comment: Mate I am not trying to put validation. I just want to show/hide a div when the current input is selected (focused).

Comment: do you have access to the HTML source? I mean can you change that part too? There is an invalid `<div>` inside `<p>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: Your HTML has a minor issue. Element 'div' cannot be nested with element 'p'

Comment: If you have access to the HTML source, update it to match this and you're good to go: http://jsfiddle.net/b0ndt/zprjkhcv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we fix the nested `<div>` like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wynLaydm/)

```
<div>
    <label for="example">Text:</label>
    <input class="example" name="example" type="text" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="tip">
        Some text...
    </div>
</div>
```

This should work:

```
$('.example').on('blur', function() {
    $('div.tip').fadeOut('medium');
});
$('.example').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).siblings('div.tip').show();
});
$('div.tip').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a5secarf/16/)

As you can see I have added an ID to each div that you want to show that relates to the input you have clicked so you can have more flexibility of where the element is places in the DOM.

Also it hides all the divs that are not relevant to the current input.

I have also moved the div's outside the p tags to make the HTML valid, as suggested in the comments.

```
$('.example').focusin(function() {
    $('.tip').hide();
    $('#tip-'+$(this).attr('id')).show();
});
$('div.tip').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery `.next()` or `.closest` doesn't work between `input` and `divs`. So you may need a workaorund like below

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/a5secarf/17/)

```
$('.example').focus(function () {
    $('div.tip').hide();
    var i = 0;

    $('.example').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
            $($('.tip')[i]).show();
        }
        i++;
    })

    $(document).bind('focusin.tip click.tip', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.tip, .example').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('.tip');
        $('div.tip').fadeOut('medium');
    });
});
$('div.tip').hide();
```