# div with background-image on the same line as some span, while being inside a p

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<p><span>Hello</span>&nbsp;<div class="show" /></p>
```

Now the `div` has the `background-image` property set to some image:

```
.show {
    background-image: url(http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I can't seem to get the `div` (or, rather, the image) on the same line as the `span` because of the `p` around the both of them. Is this even possible while keeping the `p`?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr5afpd0/1/) showcasing the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put `div` elements inside `<p>` elements. One simple way to fix it would be to replace `div` for `span`.

```
<p><span>Hello</span>&nbsp;<span class="show" /></p>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that and VS suppressed the warning about the `div` inside a `p` because both were inside an `ItemTemplate`... but good to know I can just use a `span` instead. Now, I've used a lot of different elements to get this to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

---

You can set display:inline-block propery to P tag

```
<p><span>Doe, John</span>&nbsp;<div class="show"></div></p>

.show {
    background-image: url(http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
p{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can check here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sainath_patil/cr5afpd0/4/)