# Paragraph outside div?

Tags: html, css

This is a problem which is hard to explain without actually showing the problem.

We start off with view-source:
[image: View-source]

Everything should be inside < p> but instead it closes < p>.

My code:

```
<p>'.bbCode($Posts['content'], $Posts['id']).'</p>';
```

and also the preg_replace creating the quote:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[quote=([^\]]+)?\]/is', '<div class="quote"><strong>$1 skrev:</strong><br />', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\[quote[^\]]+\]/is', '<div class=\"quote\"><br />', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\[\/quote\]/is', '<br clear=\"all\" /></div>', $text);
```

Comment: My guess is that your HTML is invalid (e.g. `<div>` inside a `<p>`) and the browser is trying to correct it. Post the rendered HTML please.

Comment: `<p>` can only contain inline elements. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: @sbeliv01 how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: Updated guidelines for html5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ (answer in sbeliv01's answer is for html4)

Comment: @user1129884 It explains why the browser renders the `<p>` tag as noted.

Comment: @sbeliv01 I always thought browsers were more forgiving on invalid html, it apears the browser does indeed try to correct this behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/LLa6yLvg/

Answer (score 0):

Use span instead of div.

```
<span class="makeSomeCoolFormattedText"> My Awesome Text </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser is trying to correct the invalid markup. You are trying to insert some block elements into `p`. Two solutions: change `p` to `section`, `article` or `div` or something else OR strip posts from html markup.