# TinyMce : Customizing new lines

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tinymce

Is there any way to put one **span** inside **p** tag(root element of tiny mce)?
I mean each new line should be

```
<p><span></span></p>
```

Any idea to achieve this?

My workarounds are these..

1. I tested `forced_root_block: 'p,span'` but it wont worked.
2. In each key press i tried to replace `<p> with <p><span> and </p> with </span></p>` but that is not reflecting in editor and i am sure the replace logic works perfectly because i printed in console that shows the expected output(`<p><span>{{my input}}</span></p>`).

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: Sorry, I put 'div' tag inside 'P' as an example,
I am looking to add a html element that can be any thing like span or h1 etc inside "P" tag.
Now i edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use this directive inside your `tinymce.init({});`

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('PostProcess', function(ed) {
        ed.content = ed.content.replace(/(<p>)/gi,'<p><span>').replace(/(<\/p>)/gi,'<\/span><\/p>');
    });
}
```

This will replace automatically all your `<p></p>` tags with `<p><span></span></p>`

Look: i'm using the PostProcess event http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.PostProcess

With a little bit of imagination you can customize that event a little bit more. Here you can see a full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/csedoardo/bbfg7x3z/

Answer (score 0):

would this achieve what you're looking for?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    forced_root_block: 'span',
    force_p_newlines: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome compatable browser TinyMCE replace new line `<div></div>` blocks.
This tags have zero lineHeight.
Use **[setup](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@setup/)** options for replace TAG

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
...
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('PostProcess', function(ed) {
                ed.content = ed.content.replace(/(<div><\/div>)/gi,'<p><\/p>');
            });
        },
...
    )}
```