# Removing a <div> section with JS does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to remove a surrounding div section from the DOM by using the following simple code:

```js
document.getElementById("1").outerHTML = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;
```

```html
<p>
    Part 1
    <div id="1">
        <span id ="2">
            Part 2
        </span>
        Part 3
    </div>
    Part 4
</p>
```

The expected output applying the script is that all parts are within one single line. However they are not. When I manually remove the div section from the HTML code they are in one line. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

Andreas

Comment: Try setting the innerHTML of the `<p>` tag. You may have to nest `<div id="1">` inside another tag for this, or keep a track of the text in the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest a block level element inside inline elements in HTML. In other words, a `div` inside a `p` is invalid in all standards of HTML. Moreover, when using a conforming HTML parser, it is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

Your code is correct if the surrounding element was a `div`.

```
<div>
    Part 1
    <div id="1">
        <span id ="2">
            Part 2
        </span>
        Part 3
    </div>
    Part 4
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Prashant, thank you for the hint. Unfortunately I don't have control over the HTML part. However it is good to know that the HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("1").outerHTML` will return (1):

```
<div id="1">
   <span id ="2">
      Part 2
   </span>
   Part 3
</div>
```

`document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;` will return (2):

```
<span id ="2">
   Part 2
</span>
Part 3
```

Your code means: Replace `(1)` with `(2)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the wrong HTML structure. Because, P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)".

[Check this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Solution: Replace the extreme P element with div. Check the link(Working Code) below.

```
<div id="3">
    Part 1
    <div id="1">
        <span id ="2">
            Part 2
        </span>
        Part 3
    </div>
    Part 4
</div>

var newHtml = document.getElementById('1').innerHTML;
document.getElementById("1").outerHTML=newHtml;
```

[Working Code](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zcx14mew/)

Comment: Dear Santhosh, thank you for the hint. Unfortunately I don't have control over the HTML part. However it is good to know that the HTML is invalid.