# how can we add a div tag inside para tag in html?

Tags: html

I want to display a division which contains some elements in it in between some text. so i thought to use div inside the para tag in html. but i can't get the thing worked. is there any appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: no, as per w3c specification p are allowed only inside division. since both are block elements.

Comment: just use a div with some margins instead of a p.

Comment: can you please elaborate your suggestion @MrLister

Comment: You should show some code first and then I can tell you what the p needs to be replaced by exactly.

Comment: cool, i made a mistake of understanding, now i got working with my expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `<p>` tag is only permitted to use "phrasing content" as specified by W3C here under "Permitted contents": http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Phrasing contents are things like `<a>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, etc. and don't include `<div>` as specified here under "Phrasing elements": http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing

And normal character data specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data

If you want elements in between your text just break it up into two separate `<p>` tags, put whatever between it, and style them with CSS to make them look how you want.