# How to append a ul tag inside a P or span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Run the following piece of jQuery:

```
$('body').append('<p><span><ul><li>test</li></ul></span></p>');
```

I would expect this:

```
<p>
  <span>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</p>
```

However, the result is this:

```
<p>
  <span></span>
</p>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Why does the ul tag break out of span and p? This is valid HTML markup.

*** UPDATE ***

The p tag seems to be the problem. If you run the following:

```
$('body').append('<span><ul><li>test</li></ul></span>');
```

then

```
<span>
  <ul>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

will generate properly.

Comment: Try appending actual element objects, and not a string

Comment: No, that's actually not valid HTML. See: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @SterlingArcher: jQuery's `append` is just fine with HTML strings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I should have clarified -- I know it works, it's just cleaner (IMO) to build the objects

Comment: FYI, I've updated my answer to address your update.

Comment: Related: [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to append a `<ul>` tag inside a `<p>` or `<span>`?

You can't, it's invalid. So what you're seeing is the browser trying to rearrange it to make it valid.

The content model of [`span` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (e.g., what they're allowed to have in them) is "[phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)" (things like `em` and such). (Same for [`p` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).) [`ul` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) are only valid where "[flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1)" (like paragraphs and divs) is expected.

To fix it, don't try to put a `ul` inside a `span` or a `p`. You could remove the `span` and the `p` and use a `div`, for instance:

```
$('body').append('<div><ul><li>test</li></ul></div>');
```

...or just use the `ul` directly without a wrapper around it.

---

Re your update:

> If you add the following markup to an html document
>
> ...
>
> And then open the page in your favorite browser, it will open correctly. Try it!

Sure — because the browser rearranges it. For instance, this snippet:

```html
<p>
  <span>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</p>
```

Is turned into this DOM by Chrome:

[image]

Note how the `ul` is **not** inside the `p` or `span` — it's exactly the result you said you were getting.

That said, browsers do a **lot** to try to tolerate invalid markup and structures. But using valid markup and structures is generally the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a block-level element inside an inline element. Also, you wouldn't normally put a list in a paragraph.

```
$('body').append('<div><ul><li>test</li></ul></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, your markup is invalid HTML and won't be parsed as you expected.

However, you can still do it using DOM manipulations.

```js
document.body
.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
.appendChild(document.createElement('span'))
.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'))
```

Not recommended because it's semantically wrong, but it's possible.

Comment: The question, of course, is, why would anybody want to do this? What purpose does this serve that you can't achieve with valid HTML?