# Froala v2 editor mangles my code upon retrieval

Tags: javascript, html, froala

I'm using the Froala editor v2 and I'm running into a very frustrating and intermittent problem. I'm embedding a custom HTML widget (a rich preview when the user enters a URL on its own line). But when I retrieve the final HTML to be saved to our database, it seems Froala decides to "clean up" my HTML before giving it to me. When I inspect the editor instance while I'm editing the content, all the markup is in good shape. But when I call `$('.froala-editor').froalaEditor('html.get')` to retrieve the HTML, the HTML for the URL preview widget is completely mangled.

My suspicion is that, since the entire preview is wrapped in an `<a>` tag to make the whole thing linked (and I don't have any nested `<a>` tags in it because that's bad HTML), Froala is taking the other structural elements like the `div`s, `h#` tags, `p` tags, etc and placing copies of the wrapping `<a>` tag inside all of them (as you'll see in the code samples) because it doesn't think you're allowed to have an `<a>` wrapping all that stuff. But that's just a guess.

And to top it all off, sometimes Froala will give me the HTML intact and other times it won't.

I don't think it makes any difference, but I'm using React to generate the widget and then injecting the resulting HTML into the editor. I've removed all the `data-reactid` attributes to reduce the clutter.

Original injected HTML (the outermost `<p>` tags are there because Froala seems to like to wrap everything in semantic block level tags):

```
<p>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="embedly-preview" title="http://www.google.com" data-source-url="http://www.google.com">
    <span class="ui media content-item-wrapper content-summary post-body">
      <span class="media-left content-summary-image post-image">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/peerlyst/image/fetch/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fimages%2Fbranding%2Fgooglelogo%2F1x%2Fgooglelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png">
      </span>
      <span class="media-body content-summary-body">
        <h2 class="content-summary-title content-title post-title">Google</h2>
        <p class="content-summary-content post-content">Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.</p>
        <p class="content-summary-link">http://www.google.com</p>
      </span>
    </span>
  </a>
</p>
```

What Froala gives me:

```
<p>
  <a class="embedly-preview" data-source-url="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="http://www.google.com">
    <span class="ui media content-item-wrapper content-summary post-body">
      <span class="media-left content-summary-image post-image">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/peerlyst/image/fetch/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com…randing%2Fgooglelogo%2F1x%2Fgooglelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png">
      </span>
      <span class="media-body content-summary-body"></span>
    </span>
  </a>
</p>
<h2 class="content-summary-title content-title post-title">
  <a class="embedly-preview" data-source-url="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</h2>
<p class="content-summary-content post-content">
  <a class="embedly-preview" data-source-url="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="http://www.google.com">Search the world&apos;s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you&apos;re looking for.</a>
</p>
<p class="content-summary-link">
  <a class="embedly-preview" data-source-url="http://www.google.com" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the editor, but the HTML structure you have. You have used a `H2` tag inside a `P` tag which browsers do not allow (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696078/1806855 for more details) You could check that in a very basic jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jLzm2b0/.

Instead it should work just fine if you'd use a `DIV` tag instead: https://jsfiddle.net/0jLzm2b0/1/. You can see the output is no longer changed.

Comment: I was originally using an `<a>` tag as the outermost wrapper and having the same issue, but it was mangling the HTML in a different way. And in HTML5, `<a>` tags are allowed to wrap block-level elements. So I added the `<p>` tag since everything in Froala is wrapped in `<p>` tag by default.

Answer (score -1):

After digging into the Froala code using a breakpoint to isolate the point at which the HTML gets mangled, turns out it's actually jQuery that's mangling my HTML. Effectively, given the original HTML from above in the variable `html`:

`$(html).html() !== html`

What's even more interesting is that (taking the relevant snippet from Froala's code where it wraps the fetched HTML in a `div` before processing):

`$('<div>' + html + '</div>').html() !== $(html).html() !== html`

(Clearly, wrapping `html` in a `<div>` will make the HTML not equal to the others, but even the HTML inside the `<div>` that is output is mangled from the original)

So the jQuery constructor is the thing being "helpful" by retooling my HTML for me.