# Why <div> block is pop out from wrapping <p> using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've noticed very strange behavior using `innerHTML`:

```js
var elem = document.body;
elem.innerHTML = '<p> <div> Inner div </div> </p>';
```

What DOM you expect to see after running this code?

Like this?

```
<body>
  <p>
    <div> Inner div </div>
  </p>
</body>
```

**Incorrect answer!** Because you will see the following DOM instead:

```
<body>
  <p></p>
  <div> Inner div </div>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

It works like that on Chrome, Safari, MS Edge, IE11 (works like expected only on Firefox).

**Does anyone know why the heck it works like this on most browsers?**

I know it's semantically wrong to add `div`s inside `p` but I can add them by `appendChild` or even by `innerHTML` on `p` element itself!

---

**P.S.** It pops out divs from any level:

```js
 elem.innerHTML = '<p><span> It breaks divs <div> at any </div> level </span></p>'
```

results in an absolute mess:

```
<body>
  <p>
    <span> It breaks divs </span>
  </p>
  <div> at any </div>
  level
  <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks for advice. Updated question

Comment: @Swaprks thanks for pointing out, I didn't know how to google this :)

Comment: @RomanGotsiy Thanks--it's a lot easier for more people to read it this way :)