# Why cant I put tags around this content without it breaking?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following 'taped box' code on a new site I am trying:

http://codepen.io/Winger15mk/pen/grjXoE

```css
html {
  background: red;
}
.mybox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.myboxtape {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 8px -2px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.62);
}
.myboxtape::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(220, 212, 176, 0.70);
  height: 125px;
}
.myboxtape::before {
  left: 45%;
  top: -60px;
  width: 28px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <p class="myboxtape">
    My Title
    <br>This is some content!
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to put the content text within `<p>` tags and `<h2>` tags, but when I do that the text jumps out of the box underneath it and I can't work out why?

Comment: I see no `<h2>` tags in your example.

Comment: @j08691: If you add one, then you can see the issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grjXQN

Answer (score 3):

Working solution: change Paragraph to a div

```css
html {
  background: red;
}
.mybox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.myboxtape {
  background: blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 8px -2px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.62);
}
.myboxtape::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(220, 212, 176, 0.70);
  height: 125px;
}
.myboxtape::before {
  left: 45%;
  top: -60px;
  width: 28px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <div class="myboxtape">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <br><h2>This is some content!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<p>` tags can't contain block level elements, see:
[Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Running a html validator on your code will ususally pick up this type of problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems you can't put an `<h2>` inside of a `<p>`.

Comment: Where did the OP say that they were putting `<h2>` elements *within* `<p>` elements?

Comment: @j08691  He says he wants to add h2 or p tags where he has his content.

Comment: I took this to mean where he has written "This is some content!".

Answer (score 3):

The `<p>` tag isn't designed to hold other elements. If you change myboxtape to a div, you should be able to put "My Title" in an h2 and "This is some content!" in a p.

Comment: Can't believe i missed this! Thanks for pointing it out! My Bad!