# Is it possible, to flow a div container right next to the last line of a p?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress template. I'm using the_content(); to get the text written in the backend. Wordpress usually wrapps that inside a `<p>`. After the_content(); I want to have a link (that is not written into the WYSIWYG-Editor), and that link is inside a div. Now I want the `<div>` to flow right next to the p-wrapped text:

`<p>`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna, sed diam.`</p>` `<div>`MY LINK`</div>`

Thanks!

Comment: `Is it possible, to flow a div container “inside” a p?` It's not inside in your example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Comment: A `<span>` would be more appropriate, since it's an inline element.

Comment: Yepp, just changed it to a span. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't understand your question correctly, but I think you mean this

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="inline">Content is here</p>
  <div class="inline"><a href="">The link</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!

Comment: the parent element should not be P tag browser will not render div inside p check in the inspect element by the way i have updated

Comment: I thought that he said both were inside a p. Initially I also put div

Comment: ok but you cannot take div or p tag inside P tag you have to take span or something else inline element

Answer (score 0):

you can use css display: inline and display: inline-block to do that

**Using inline-block**

```html
     <p style="display: inline-block;"> Content of p tag </p>
    <div style="display: inline-block;"> <a href="#">Content of div tag </a></div>
```

**Using inline:**

```html
<p style="display: inline;"> Content of p tag </p>
<div style="display: inline;"> <a href="#">Content of div tag </a></div>
```