# AngularJS: Why is the ng-controller behaving odd with ng-show and ng-click and <p> tag?

Tags: angularjs

Here's the code snippet of the Angular js app.

```js
var app = angular.module("list", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.get = function() {
    $scope.thiss = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true">
  <p ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

i have been learning AngularJS. I cannot understand why this simple example fails to work. I have been followng w3cschools tutorial and the syntax seem to perfect align with it. Is it something to with scoping ? or do i have to bind ng-show with model data.

I also did the following but it doesnot seem to work.

```
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true">
     <p ng-controller="myctrl" >
     <button ng-click="thiss=false">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss"> This is it</p>
     </p>
</div>
```

Why is placing the controller on the div tag works ? But fails to work when it is in the child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't try to make your HTML standard, follow some rule defined by HTML. 
Don't put nested `<p>` tags. AngularJS sometimes don't work for invalid DOM. I used `<span>` tag instead of nested `<p>` works fine.

```js
var app = angular.module("list", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.get = function() {
    $scope.thiss = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true">
  <p ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <span ng-show="thiss">This is it</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

For more information validate HTML. Please, check following HTML code at: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<p>
</p>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bro my question is " Why is placing the controller on the div tag works ? But fails to work when it is in the child element?"

Comment: you clearly see above i put controller declaration on <p> tag as like your code

Comment: Thanks bro. BTW is using <div> inside a <div> also not valid according to HTML standard?

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because you have a <p> tag within a <p> tag. It should work if you change you code as follows.

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl" >
    <button ng-click="thiss=false">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss"> This is it</p>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("list", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.get = function() {
    $scope.thiss = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it) for the reason why <p> cannot include block level elements

Comment: @Sohil, Not sure what does not work. I have copied your same code and changed parent paragraph tag to div and it works.

Comment: It seems you have reedited your answer. It wasnt working the first time

Comment: I have re-edited to include the code snippet. But the original answer remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```js
var app=angular.module("list",[]);
  app.controller("myctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.get=function(){
       $scope.thiss = false;
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <p ng-init="thiss=true">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    {{thiss}}
    <p ng-show="thiss">Show Content</p>
    <p ng-show="!thiss">Hidden Content</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code worked but my question is why didnt it worked on the first place? Am  i missing out any important concept?

Comment: @Sohil: You need to use ng-model to consider it as a scope variable or scope variable needs to be called defined as object reference.

Comment: @Sohil : I've edited my answers, it shows if you put ng-app and ng-controller on same elements then it's working

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. But writing both ng-controller and ng-app on the same div tag restrict of having multiple controller?

Comment: @Sohil: I am still finding the reason why this happens with your code, but if my code helps you then mark it.

Comment: I have upvoted it but it hasnt answered the question about the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have just remove `ng-controller` from `<p>` and put it inside `div` with `ng-app`. don't know the reason behind this behavior of angularjs but it works as you want.

```js
var app = angular.module("list", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.get = function() {
    $scope.thiss = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <p>
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It did work when we put ng-controller in the div tag but is there any specific reason for the beahviour of Angular JS . ?

Comment: Nop.. i didn't know about this.. will update my answer if i found anything related to this.

Answer (score 0):

> try after removing the blank array from the dependency

```
var app = angular.module('list');
```

> make sure that the controller should be placed in `<div ng-controller="myctrl">`

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
 <p ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
    </p>
```

this is how a browser interprets html according to DOM :

```
    <p ng-controller="myctrl">
     <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
   </p>
   <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
   <p></p>
```

therefore the scope of your controller "myctrl" does not apply on nested para, 
try using div instead of nested `<p>`

```
var app = angular.module("list", []);
app.controller("myctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.get = function() {
    $scope.thiss = false;
  }
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="list" ng-init="thiss = true">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    <p ng-show="thiss">This is it</p>
  </div>
</div>
```