# Why is the W3 Validator stating that there is a closing </p> with no opening one?

Tags: html, validation

I tried to [validate](https://validator.w3.org) the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    This is some <b>text</b>
      <ul>
        <li>A bullet point</li>
        <li>another bullet point</li>
      </ul>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It [renders as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/h1esv21o/), but the Validator throws the following error:

[image]

It looks to me that there is a proper pair `<p>(...)</p>`, **why the error then?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: Invalid markup can produce all kinds of results in all kinds of things.

Comment: @Rob Admittedly this error is rather unintuitive and non-obvious though…

Comment: @deceze It should be immediately obvious from the very inclusion of a `<ul>`.

Comment: @Rob *If* you know that `ul` inside a `p` is a no-no… If you don't expect that restriction, this particular error message is rather confounding.

Comment: @deceze The same can be said of any error produced by any error checking software. I understand your point if one is coming from a point of view that does not know HTML and does not understand error checking.

Comment: @Rob Just saying that *"looks like you're trying to nest a `ul` inside a `p`, be advised that the `p` will be prematurely closed here"* would be a much easier to digest error message. I'm also aware that that's much harder to produce for the validator, given that `<p><ul>` isn't even invalid syntax…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your DOM inspector how it *actually* renders. You'll see something like:

```
<p>...</p>
<ul>...</ul>
```

A `ul` element cannot be nested inside a `p` element. The presence of `<ul>` implicitly closes the `<p>` at that point. The trailing `</p>` is therefore left without context.

The reasoning in the official specification is:

> `p`
>   Permitted contents: Phrasing content.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

> `ul`
>   Permitted parent elements:  Any element that can contain flow elements.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

Answer (score 3):

Because you have nested a list in your paragraph which is not allowed for them.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is some <b>text</b></p>
    <ul>
        <li>A bullet point</li>
        <li>another bullet point</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[w3schools p-Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp)

Comment: And why is that forbidden?

Comment: More specifically, [`<p>` elements can only contain Phrasing Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p).

Comment: Because it doesn't conform to the validator standards... Why do you want to put your list in a Paragraph? P is usually for blocks of text not lists.....

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are nesting a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) inside the p tag which is invalid. You can only nest inline elements such as span, a and img inside p tag. So your markup is invalid, consider making something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <p>This is some <b>text</b></p>
      <ul>
        <li>A bullet point</li>
        <li>another bullet point</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be careful, `<!DOCTYPE html>` specifies HTML5, but you are referencing the HTML4 specification.

Comment: Thanks, but I gave the HTML5 documentation. Please see it

Comment: And from your (edited) link: *The distinction of block-level vs. inline elements is used in HTML specifications up  to 4.01. In HTML5, this binary distinction is replaced with a more complex set of content categories. The "block-level" category roughly corresponds to the category of flow content in HTML5, while "inline" corresponds to phrasing content, but there are additional categories.*

Answer (score 0):

I am guesing that the p tag is not ment to wrap a list 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer would be found in [here](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).
You should end your `<p>` tag before you add a list. Or you can also just don't put a `<p>` tag like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  This is some <b>text</b>
  <ul>
    <li>A bullet point</li>
    <li>another bullet point</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```