# descendant selector not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, descendant

When I try to target all anchor elements inside the p element using a descendant selector. Rules only apply to child elements and not the nested elements.

```css
p a {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
  <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a> 
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: a fiddle or a stack snippet please

Comment: Its because the div is a block element and it will appear as block untill you make it inline also.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rajinirajadev/vbfqjymg/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your html is invalid, try to replace `p` with `div`. It should work. Something like below -

```css
div a {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
  <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a>  
  </div>
</div>
```

For details - [Why `<p>` tag can't contain `<div>` tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

Comment: Clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 1):

A `p` tag cannot have a `div` tag inside it. Since this is an invalid html your browser corrects that for you. It closes the `p` tag as soon as it sees the `div` tag. And also adds a starting `p` tag for the closing `p` tag

Your actual HTML

```
<p>
   <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
   <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
   <div>
        <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a>  
   </div>
</p>
```

What it actually renders to

```
<p>
   <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
   <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
</p>
<div>
   <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a>  
</div>
<p></p>
```

And since the `a` tag with text `channel9` is not inside a `p` tag, your css does not have any effect

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use div inside a p element

```css
p a {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
  <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
  <span>
    <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a> 
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
   <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
   <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
   <div>
        <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a>  
   </div>
</p>
```

css

```
a {
   display: inline;
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code instead of above code.

```css
.clr-rd a {
  color: red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clr-rd">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.reddit.com">Go to Reddit website</a>
    <a href="http://www.quora.com">Go to QUORA</a>
    <div>
      <a href="http://www.channel9.com">channel9</a> 
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```