# How to in PHP echo html tag and variable containig html tag?

Tags: php, html, echo

Sample PHP code:

```
$a = "<ul><li>Some text</li></ul>";
```

and I want echo that with another html code:

```
<div>
  <?php echo "<p>".$a."</p>"; ?>
</div>
```

I suppose that list will be wrapped by 'p' which will be wrapped by 'div', but instead browser parse it like this:

```
<div>
  <p></p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some text</li>
    </ul>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I don'n know what's wrong.

Comment: it gives me `<div>
    <p><ul><li>Some text</li></ul></p></div>
` . No issues

Comment: it gives me <div> <p><ul><li>Some text</li></ul></p></div>  same no issue

Comment: when we do inspect element , it gives what OP says but when we do view source, seems no issue. gives `<div> <p><ul><li>Some text</li></ul></p></div>` I also want to know the reason.

Comment: that's the point, @Bhaskar, but why all browsers do it?

Comment: <p> can't contain block elements -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: YES! the <P> was the problem. So simple. Thank You.