# (key,value) in object loop with nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat iteration like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="(label,field) in app.config.properties">
                <span class="radio-group" > 
                        <div ng-repeat="option in x.options">
                              {{label}}
                        </div>
                    </span>

</p>
```

I am unable to access the label inside nested loop. I also tried using $parent.label but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is x? if there is no x then there will be no output

Comment: x is another independent object and it exists...

Comment: If `x.options` is empty, you won't see `label`, please check if it has any elements.

Comment: yes it has elements!

Comment: doesn't work! In case that helps, this is a custom directive

Comment: we would keep guessing problem and never reach solution.. or you could provide a verifiable example (code snippet or plunker) to get it solved

Comment: Can you show how your objects look like? `config.properties` and `x` ?

Comment: How does your directive look like?

Comment: <div> tag cannot be inside <p> tag...Change either <div> or <p> to make it work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an issue about `<p>` and `ng-repeat`(`<p>` doesn't show), when I changed `<p>` to `<div>`, it's working well.

**UPD:**

You can move inside `ng-repeat` to `<span>` and remove the `<div>` in it, this way will work with `<p>`, this is also commented by @ Karan Desai.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.app = {
      config: {
        properties: [
          {id:1},
          {id:2},
          {id:3},
          {id:4}
        ]
      }
    };
    $scope.x = {
      options: [
        {
          id: 1
        },
        {
          id: 2
        }
      ]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="(label,field) in app.config.properties">
    <span class="radio-group" ng-repeat="option in x.options">
      {{label}}
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```