# Angular 4 condition nested in loop

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

can you help me fix my code of ng4? I have array of user models, which every have property firstName, lastName, and age like that:

```
export class User {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public age: number;

    constructor(fName: string, lName: string, age: number) {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Here is my component.ts code:

```
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];

  constructor() { 
    this.users = [
      new User("John", "", 16),
      new User("Jose", "", 45),
      new User("Xavier", "", 22)
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

When I tried it without condition in template, it was working. After I've added condition, I have this issues:

> Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already
>   been closed by another tag.

Do you have idea what I did wrong? Here is code of html template:

```
<p *ngFor="let user of users">
  <div *ngIf="user.age > 20; then old else young"></div>
  <ng-template #old>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too old - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
  <ng-template #young>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too years young - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**p** tag can contain only inline elements

Change `div` to `span`(inline element)

[Why p tag can't contain div tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PWgklfXDOfPXR6M0bnf5?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Use **`div`** instead of p

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <div *ngIf="user.age > 20; then old else young"></div>
  <ng-template #old>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too old - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
  <ng-template #young>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too years young - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
</div >
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<div>` to `<ng-template>`:

```html
<p *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ng-template *ngIf="user.age > 20; then old else young"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #young>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too years young - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
    <ng-template #old>Hello, my name is {{user.firstName}} and I'm too old - {{user.age}}.</ng-template>
</p>
```

The reason is that it's not recommended you put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`, so Angular throws an error. You can test it doing something like this:

```html
<p><div>This will throw the same error in Angular</div></p>
```