# <p> tag closing outside containing block in nbconvert template

Tags: html, css, jinja2, nbconvert

Ok , I am trying to modify [nbconvert template](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) in order to change some style when coverting to html using template , (that I am new to, and it said it's in [Jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) style)

here's the code (of problem) in `full.tpl`:

```
{% block markdowncell  %}
<p dir="rtl" style="text-align:right;">
{{ super() }}
</p>
{% endblock markdowncell %}
```

it should include the cell inside right-aliged text, put the result after many tries is the same (first run worked , then I changed sth ,and it broke)

in the browser it shows that the

close before the content , like this:

```
<p .. > </p>
<div> ... </div> <!-- that should be inside p tag which is `{{super()}}`-->
```

div tag ,however, would work , but i need `dir=rtl` also.

The complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/engyasin/a96ebb884ff66a52ead83dd6e0c759a6)

any help would be appricated , I spend a lot of time on it, with no use, :(

Comment: use <div> instead of <p> tag..this can be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: @ManishPatel ok , that, explain but didn't solve ,is there a css style equlivent to dir='rtl' in <p> but for <div> , I have no access to the inner <div> ...

Comment: @YasinYousif Please read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir): _The `dir` **global attribute** is an enumerated attribute..._ So it should work with DIV, and you can alwyas use simple and basic CSS: `.rtl {direction: rtl;}` and apply the `rtl` class on the relevan element in the DOM