# Web component and shadow root

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, html5-template, native-web-component

I create a web component with this code where I use template:

```
let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
tmpl.innerHTML =`<style>
div {
   color: green;
   display: inline;
   margin: 3px;
}

p {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<p>
Hello my name is:
<div>Web</div>
<div>Component</div>
</p>`;
this.shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
```

But in shadow root from console I see this content which not the same:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Shadow DOM or Custom Element.

Actually the same behaviour happens with normal DOM : you cannot insert a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` element. The latter only accepts *phrasing content*.

See SO question: [Why `<p>` tag can't contain `<div>` tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8397852/4600982)