# css selector p > div has no effect

Tags: html, css

I am trying to restyle div's who reside inside p elements (such are automatically created when using content editable on text). But selector have no effect - div > p works whereas p > div doesn't.

```css
div > p{
  background-color: yellow;
}

p > div{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>123<p>45</p></div>
<p>123<div>45</div></p>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZxmrm

Comment: p element can not have div element as a child

Comment: for more detail follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: You can't add `div` inside a `p` tag as per w3c standard. Read more about in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: as stated in the question, this situation is automatically created if you use contenteditable, press enter when caret at the end

Comment: `<p>123<div>45</div></p>` is invalid html. The DOM created by the browser out of that invalid html will be `<p>123</p><div>45</div><p></p>`. And only the created DOM is relevant for the css rules.