# How mix <div> with paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, styles, inline

I have DIVs that are styled as interactive icon widgets, and I want to mix them with text like IMGs. I understand that [DIVs aren't allowed in Ps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it). However, is it possible to make the DIVs *look like* part of the text? I would use SPAN or I, but a 3rd-party requirement forces me to use DIVs.

The following code

```
<p>Text before DIV</p>
<div class="my_icon"></div>
<p>Text after DIV</p>
```

Should ideally look similar to:

```
<p>Text before DIV<img class="my_icon">Text after DIV</p>
```

Comment: `p, div { display: inline }`

Comment: `3rd-party requirement forces me to use DIVs` --> force him to understand that it's not suitable

Comment: @LGSon making the `p`s `inline` would make them behave very differently from a normal `p`. I don't think the dupe really answers this specific question.

Comment: @Turnip As I understood it, they need a `div` inside a `p`, with text before, inside and after the `div`, all on one line, and as they said they generally would use a `span` inside the `p`, they way to accomplish that is simply to make them all display inline.

Comment: It will certainly accomplish that, but will break the usual behaviour of a `p`. If there was an image before or after, for example, they would behave unlike a normal `p`. http://jsfiddle.net/va3ekqtw/7/ . I can't think of a better solution though.

Comment: @Turnip The dupe show how, this fiddle show to limit the specific `p`'s: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y1vwpc/2/

Comment: Phil, here is how to make use of `display: inline/-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y1vwpc/2/

Comment: @LGSon that doesn't really work though http://jsfiddle.net/g4y1vwpc/4/

Comment: @Turnip Well, there is thousand ways to break a code..., and as we do that already, simply wrap them: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y1vwpc/6/ ... still, the display type `inline/-block` needs to be involved, hence the dupe.

Comment: @Turnip This might be the best though, using Flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/g4y1vwpc/7/

Comment: Can you use other inline elements, like `i`? If so, that won't mess with your semantics, and you can use it instead of `div`/`span`?

Comment: @Hans I'm afraid the use of DIV (block-level element) is non-negotiable. If I can't style DIVs like inline images, I guess I could fall back to providing options for aligning them via float...:p

Comment: @PhilKang: It's not semantically clean, but can you replace `p`s with `div`s? This would allow you to have the nested structure you're looking for, and you can make the nested icon div display `inline`.