# To replace a div element to the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using below code for replacing links:

```
function replaceLink(href_array){
    $('.externalLink').each(function(index){
        $(this).replaceWith(function() {
            if ($(this).text() != "") {
                return $('<a />').append($(this).contents()).attr('href', href_array[index]);
            }
            else { // do not use
                return $('<a />').append(href_array[index]).attr('href', href_array[index]);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The initial page has the following structure:

```
body 
    p div.externalLink /p
    p div.externalLink /p
    p div.externalLink /p
    p div.externalLink /p
    p div.externalLink /p
    p div.externalLink /p
/body
```

After the script, it should be:

```
body 
    p a#href /p
    p a#href /p
    p a#href /p
    p a#href /p
    p a#href /p
    p a#href /p
/body
```

But it turns out like this:

```
body 
    p /p a#href
    p /p a#href 
    p /p a#href
    p /p a#href
    p /p a#href
    p /p a#href
/body
```

How can I correct this?

[at the bottom as it should be on top of how it turns out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LXMz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `div` tags inside `p` tags, which is incorrect and the opening `div` tag will automatically close the `p` tag before it, hence the `replaceWith` works incorrectly.

Try a `div` inside `div`.

Source - [Why can't the <p> tag contain a <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it)

```js
var href_array = [
  "Href1", "Href2", "Href3", "Href4", "Href5", "Href6"
]

function replaceLink(href_array) {
  $('.externalLink').each(function(index) {
    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
      if ($(this).text() != "") {
        return $('<a />').append($(this).contents()).attr('href', href_array[index]);
      } else { // do not use
        return $('<a />').append(href_array[index]).attr('href', href_array[index]);
      }
    });
  });
}

replaceLink(href_array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">A</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">B</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">C</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">D</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">E</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="externalLink">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeap it is. but script change div to the link. 

p.s With div work

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand that, did using the above approach solve your issue?

Comment: Can you check the code snippet and change it according to your needs?

Comment: yeah I did it when you said replace P with div.
p.s Work