# DIV text formatting inconsistency

Tags: html, css

I've stumbled upon `<div>` behavior I've never noticed.

`<div>` doesn't inherit text formatting styles from the `<p>` tag. Only from the `<p>` tag. Even when using class selector.

https://codepen.io/elaman/pen/JjjRvWB

Is there any documented explanation to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

```
p, a, section, .test ,div{
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting div tags within p tags is invalid in HTML. If you open this in the browser and click inspect elements you'll see that the browser is creating 2 p tags on either side of the div and it is no longer nested. So the div cannot inherit anything from a p tag.

Answer (score 0):

As per W3 validation, this is not a valid p tag not contain div element.
so check in inspect or view page source div tag is outside of p automatically that's why p tag style did not apply on div tag.