# Display a table on hover for elements in multiple rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to display a table on hover for elements in rows and columns.
Note: The data in the rows and columns is also in an accordion.
The data is in 4 columns and can be any number of rows.
The data for each table to be displayed on hover contains 5 columns and can be any number of rows.

I have written the following CSS/HTML that displays all 4 columns of data (i.e. jockey name and number of rides) when the accordion is opened.
Note: Each of these elements will have an associated table to be displayed on hover.

As you will see, I managed to display the associated table for each element on hover in the first row, however, I have been unable to do the same for any of the subsequent elements in the remaining rows and columns.

Note: For testing purposes, I have intentionally left the highlighting of each element in 'red' when hovered.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #388070;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto !Important;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #388070;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #388070;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: "\002B";
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  color: #388070;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  color: #388070;
  content: "\2212";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.panel5 {
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
  column-gap: 3px;
}

.myrow {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
}

.myrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #07342a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#jockeys {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

#jockeys td,
#jockeys th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#jockeys th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

#jockeys tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#ShowJockey:hover+#jockeys {
  display: block;
}

div.hoverPopUp {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.hoverPopUp td,
div.hoverPopUp th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

div.hoverPopUp th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.hoverHereToPopUp {
  background-color: white;
  color: #07342a;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.hoverHereToPopUp:hover+div.hoverPopUp {
  display: block;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
<div class="panel5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">ADAM HYERONIMUS HAS 5 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="hoverPopUp">
        <table class="center">
          <tr>
            <th>RACECOURSE</th>
            <th>RACE NO.</th>
            <th>RUNNER</th>
            <th>TRAINER</th>
            <th>TD RATING</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 1</td>
            <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td>
            <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 2</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 3</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 4</td>
            <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AAA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 5</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 6</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AAA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 7</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 8</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AAA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>

      <p>
        <p align="left" style="line-height: 16px letter-spacing: 1px;">
          <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
        </p>

        <p>
          <p align="left" style="line-height: 16px letter-spacing: 1px;">
            <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <p align="left" style="line-height: 16px letter-spacing: 1px;">
              <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
            </p>

    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</a>

      <div class="hoverPopUp">

        <table class="center">

          <tr>
            <th>RACECOURSE</th>
            <th>RACE NO.</th>
            <th>RUNNER</th>
            <th>TRAINER</th>
            <th>TD RATING</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 1</td>
            <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - TWO (8)</td>
            <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 3</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 5</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>

      <p>
        <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
          <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">JAMES MCDONALD HAS 6 RIDES.</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
            <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
              <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
            </p>

    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</a>

      <div class="hoverPopUp">

        <table class="center">

          <tr>
            <th>RACECOURSE</th>
            <th>RACE NO.</th>
            <th>RUNNER</th>
            <th>TRAINER</th>
            <th>TD RATING</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 1</td>
            <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - THREE (8)</td>
            <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 2</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 3</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - THREE (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 8</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AAA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>

      <p>
        <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
          <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
            <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
              <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
            </p>

    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</a>

      <div class="hoverPopUp">

        <table class="center">

          <tr>
            <th>RACECOURSE</th>
            <th>RACE NO.</th>
            <th>RUNNER</th>
            <th>TRAINER</th>
            <th>TD RATING</th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 1</td>
            <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - FOUR (8)</td>
            <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 2</td>
            <td>PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>
                <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
              </center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 4</td>
            <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AAA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 5</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
            <td>RACE 7</td>
            <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
            <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
            <td>
              <center>AA</center>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </div>

      <p>
        <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
          <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
            <a href="#" id="ShowJockey">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <p align="left" style="line-height:16px letter-spacing:6px;">
            </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

If I attempt to add the same  and  code to the subsequent element(s) in the column DIV(s) (i.e. the elements currently contained within the paragraph tag, that should be row 2, row 3 and so on..., I lose the column structure & format, and the defined a href's are all misaligned and partially or completely hidden until hovered.

Note: The jockey names should appear in alphabetical order from left to right.

In addition but not as important as the aforementioned, it appears that the table displayed is limited to the width of the column. When I attempt to expand the width, the right side of the table gets hidden by the next column (table is behind columns to its right). I'd also like to know if there's a way to get around this and display the table "on top" (over) of the additional columns so I can expand the width.

Apologies for the length of the HTML but I think it's required for you to see what's going on.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/MWKQZbP 
I did this, But if you could make the requirement more clear, More enhancement can be done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon I have found another possible solution to your problem. With this solution, contrary to the other also great answers, there is no separate 'hover me' or 'click me' button. Just hover over a cell and view the associated table.

I have cleaned up and changed your html code a bit to make it a `<table>`. Which comes with a lot of benefits such as a nice and clean structure.

Now, each individual data cell in the `.overall` table has an attribute `onmouseover="showDetail(this.id)"`so that, when you hover over the element it fires that function and passes the id (`Jockey-#`) to the function `showDetail`.

This function first sets the opacity of all the other cells to `0.3` to make the `.hoverPopUp` stand more out to the background. Next, the opacity of the hovered cell is set to `1`. So that users know what the table is about.

Then the x and y position of the cell itself are calculated to set the position of the `detailTable` just below the selected cell.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function showDetail(jockeyId) {
  setClassOpacity("hoverHereToPopUp", 0.3);

  //get the selected cell
  var jockeyCell = document.getElementById(jockeyId);
  let jockeyDetailId = jockeyId + '-detail';
  jockeyCell.style.opacity = 1;
  jockeyCell.onmouseout = function() {
    if (detail = document.getElementById(jockeyDetailId)) {
      detail.style.display = "none";
    }
    setClassOpacity("hoverHereToPopUp", 1);
  }
  //get the relative parent of each cell
  //                    cell        <tr>          <tbody>     <table>         <div id="panel-#">
  var jockeyParent = jockeyCell.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;

  //calculate the position of the selected cell
  let cellPos = {};
  //get the position relative to it's parent
  let bodyRect = jockeyParent.getBoundingClientRect();
  let jockeyRect = jockeyCell.getBoundingClientRect();
  cellPos.x = jockeyRect.left - bodyRect.left;
  cellPos.y = jockeyRect.top - bodyRect.top;

  //set position of ".hoverPopUp" thus the detail tabe
  var dataDiv = document.getElementById(jockeyDetailId);
  if (!dataDiv) {
    //no table specified so create an empty one just for now
    let temporaryTable = `<div class="hoverPopUp" id="${jockeyDetailId}">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>No data</td>
          <td>No data</td>
          <td>No data</td>
          <td>No data</td>
          <td>No data</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>`;
    jockeyParent.innerHTML += temporaryTable;
    dataDiv = document.getElementById(jockeyDetailId);
  }
  if (cellPos.x < bodyRect.width / 2) {
    dataDiv.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    dataDiv.style.right = 0;
  }
  dataDiv.style.top = (cellPos.y + 1.5 * jockeyRect.height) + "px";
  dataDiv.style.display = "block";


}

//set the opacity of all the other elements lower to increase clarity and readability
function setClassOpacity(className, opacity) {
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    cell.style.opacity = opacity;
  }
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #388070;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0 border-bottom: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto !Important;
}

.accordion:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #388070;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #388070;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: "\002B";
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  color: #388070;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  color: #388070;
  content: "\2212";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}


/* Renamed .panel5 to .panel */


/* Each panel has now an id of #panel-# */

.panel {
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.panel:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.overall {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
}

.overall td {
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.overall tr {
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Default table styles above*/

.hoverPopUp {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Adds some depth and clarity */
  z-index: 5 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}

.jockeys {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.jockeys td,
.jockeys th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.jockeys th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

.jockeys tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3>Some nice data</h3>
  <button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-1">
    <table class="overall">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-1" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ADAM HYERONIMUS HAS 5 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-2" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-3" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-4" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-5" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-6" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JAMES MCDONALD HAS 6 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-7" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-8" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-9" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-10" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-11" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-12" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-13" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-14" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-15" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-16" class="hoverHereToPopUp"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-1-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 4</td>
          <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 6</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 7</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 8</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-6-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-11-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - THREE (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - THREE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 8</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-13-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          No data available
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-14-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 4</td>
          <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 7</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p>Well well more data</p>
  <button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
  <div class="panel" id="panel-2">
    <table class="overall">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-17" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ADAM HYERONIMUS HAS 5 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-18" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-19" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-20" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-21" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-22" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JAMES MCDONALD HAS 6 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-23" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-24" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-25" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-26" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-27" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-28" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="Jockey-29" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-30" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-31" class="hoverHereToPopUp" onmouseover="showDetail(this.id);">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</td>
          <td id="Jockey-32" class="hoverHereToPopUp"></td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-17-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 4</td>
          <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 6</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 7</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 8</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-22-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - TWO (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-28-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - THREE (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 3</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - THREE (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 8</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - THREE (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-32-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          No data available
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="hoverPopUp" id="Jockey-30-detail">
      <table class="jockeys">
        <tr>
          <th>RACECOURSE</th>
          <th>RACE NO.</th>
          <th>RUNNER</th>
          <th>TRAINER</th>
          <th>TD RATING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 1</td>
          <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 2</td>
          <td>PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>
              <font color="green"><b>AAA</b></font>
            </center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 4</td>
          <td>BIG FAT PURE FUEGO - FOUR (1)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AAA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 5</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td>
          <td>RACE 7</td>
          <td>ENTREAT - FOUR (8)</td>
          <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td>
          <td>
            <center>AA</center>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
```

Btw, where do you get this data from? If it is an api or something, I would highly advise you to create the tables with code, on page load. That will save you a lot of time.

Hope this helps! If not, please comment

### Edit

I have made the `standardTable` now relative. Also instead of `.panel5` each panel now has an class of `panel` and an id of `panel-#` in order to identify them. I assumed that every jockey in every panel is unique, if that isn't the case I might have to rewrite some bits. Also added a `box-shadow` and a `z-index` to the detail tables to make them more visible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice work here @Chiel One thing I neglected to mention is that there will be multiple accordions on each page, displayed one after another, like a list, if you will. So, when an accordion is opened, upon hover, the table needs to be displayed on top of the subsequent accordions, whether they are open or not.

Comment: @BillyJ  Oké great, I see. So (just to be sure) at any given moment, only 1 ‘detail’-table is visible? It is a simple fix: the ‘showDetail’ function should calculate the distance between the accordion and the top of the page. Then add that value to the ‘cellPos.y’ and it should work. However I am on mobile now and won’t be able to fix it until tomorrow morning... sorry

Comment: @BillyJ Because there appear to be multiple instances of the table, the code will only work with the first table (for now) because that contains the unique id’s. I will have to rewrite it a bit tomorrow (since i didn’t know that at the time of publishing the answer) to make it work with multiple accordions

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, that is correct, only 1 ‘detail’-table should be visible at a time on hover and there will "always" be a table for each 'detail' (i.e. jockey number of rides, etc.) within each accordion. I look forward to your reply.

Comment: @BillyJ I hope it now looks like as how you intended it to be!

Comment: This looks great! Thanks for all your efforts here. I'm going to have a play around with it now and let you know if I have any questions. Cheers!

Comment: @BillyJ great to see that it helped you!

Comment: Hi @Chiel I discovered an issue with the code. In our test data, we used 4 rows of data for each panel for each accordion. Once I go above 4 rows of data, the accordion does not display correctly. The data (rows) in the panel display outside of the border and overlap the next button. I've been testing a number of property changes but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @BillyJ , when adding rows, did you just copy the row above or did you add rows with custom id's (`Jockey-{#}`)? Because when I just clone the row with jockeys, the `.hoverPopUp` won't disappear when I don't hover over it. Is this your ploblem?

Comment: I've added rows with new, consecutive custom id's. (Note: I actually create this file with new data each day so the number of rows fluctuates for each panel and the number of rows can range from 1 to 20). The problem is that when there are more than 4 rows, the additional rows "overflow" outside the border of the panel and display over the next button. I've tinkered with the display, height, padding, position and overflow properties but I can't seen to get it to display properly. As a test, change the border in the panel to "red" and add a couple of rows and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hi, I think I have solved it: change the height property of `panel` from `150px` to auto. See here : `.panel {
  ...
  height: auto;
  ...
}` Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh, yes. I think you have. ;-) Thank you very much, my friend. It looks great! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

1. An id cannot be used more than once on a page. So I replaced them with `class`. (`#jockeys` -> `.jockeys`, `#ShowJockey` -> `.ShowJockey`)
2. You cannot put `div` in a `p` tag. So we have to replace `p` tags with `div`.

> In short, it is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in
> the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>`
> element. <sup>[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it)</sup>

I made a snippet.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #388070;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto !Important;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #388070;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #388070;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: "\002B";
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  color: #388070;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  color: #388070;
  content: "\2212";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.panel5 {
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
  column-gap: 3px;
}

.myrow {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
}

.myrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #07342a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jockeys {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.jockeys td,
.jockeys th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.jockeys th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

.jockeys tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.ShowJockey:hover+.jockeys {
  display: block;
}

.hoverPopUp {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hoverPopUp td,
.hoverPopUp th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hoverPopUp th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.hoverHereToPopUp {
  background-color: white;
  color: #07342a;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.hoverHereToPopUp:hover+.hoverPopUp {
  display: block;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 1;
}

.parentDiv {
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;  
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
<div class="panel5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">hover here</a>
      <div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="hoverHereToPopUp" >JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</a> <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">hover here</a>
        <div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>

      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also here I show the tables with a much better method. But you have to give your tables with the `data-hover-content` attribute. See on 1. and 6. links.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

const links = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverHereToPopUp");

[...links].forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  link.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  link.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
});

function handlePosition(e) {
  const ID = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-id");
  const wrapper = document.getElementById(ID);
  let top = "";
  if (!(e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + wrapper.offsetHeight > innerHeight)) {
    top = `${e.clientY + e.target.offsetHeight}px`;
  } else {
    top = `${e.clientY - (wrapper.offsetHeight + e.target.offsetHeight)}px`;
  }

  if (`${e.clientX -
        wrapper.offsetWidth / 2}` <= 0) {
    return `position: fixed; left: 0px; top:${top}`;
  } else {
    return `position: fixed; left: ${e.clientX -
                wrapper.offsetWidth / 2}px; top:${top}`;
  }


}

function handleMouseOver(e) {
  const hoverContent = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-content");
  const ID = Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substr(2, 9);
  const wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
  e.target.setAttribute("data-hover-id", ID);
  wrapper.setAttribute("data-hover-wrapper", "");
  wrapper.setAttribute("id", ID);
  wrapper.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0; transform: scale(.8)");
  wrapper.innerHTML = hoverContent;
  document.body.append(wrapper);
  wrapper.setAttribute("style", handlePosition(e));
}

function handleMouseLeave(e) {
  const ID = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-id");
  document.getElementById(ID).style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById(ID).style.transform = "scale(.8)";
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById(ID).remove();
  }, 150);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  const ID = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-id");
  const wrapper = document.getElementById(ID);
  wrapper.setAttribute("style", handlePosition(e));
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('[data-hover-wrapper]');
  if (wrapper) wrapper.remove();
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #388070;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto !Important;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #388070;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  color: #388070;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: "\002B";
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  color: #388070;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  color: #388070;
  content: "\2212";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.panel5 {
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
  column-gap: 3px;
}

.myrow {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 7pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: white;
}

.myrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #07342a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jockeys {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.jockeys td,
.jockeys th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

.jockeys th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}

.jockeys tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.ShowJockey:hover+.jockeys {
  display: block;
}

.hoverPopUp {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hoverPopUp td,
.hoverPopUp th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hoverPopUp th {
  background-color: #07342a;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

a.hoverHereToPopUp {
  background-color: white;
  color: #07342a;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-spacing: 1;
}

[data-hover-wrapper] {
  transition: opacity .3s, transform .3s
}

.parentDiv {
  line-height: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;  
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
<div class="panel5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp" data-hover-content="<div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>">hover here
              </a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="hoverHereToPopUp" >JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>

      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="column">

      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</a>


      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp" data-hover-content="<div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>">hover here</a>

      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I compressed the table's code because Stackoverflow snippets does not allow to too much code.

Here's an another example. (**I think best**) This works with click.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

const links = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverHereToPopUp");

[...links].forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

function handlePosition(e) {
  const ID = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-id");
  const wrapper = document.getElementById(ID);

  if (`${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left}` <= 0) {
    return `position: fixed; left: 0px; top:${
      e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + 20
    }`;
  } else {
    return `position: fixed; left: ${
      e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left
    }px; top:${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + 20}px`;
  }
}

function handleClick(e) {
  const others = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hover-wrapper]");
  others.forEach((p) => {
    p.style.opacity = 0;
    p.style.transform = "scale(.8)";

    setTimeout(() => {
      p.remove();
    }, 150);
  });

  const hoverContent = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-content");
  const ID = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  const wrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
  e.target.setAttribute("data-hover-id", ID);
  wrapper.setAttribute("data-hover-wrapper", "");
  wrapper.setAttribute("id", ID);
  wrapper.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0; transform: scale(.8)");
  wrapper.innerHTML = hoverContent;
  document.body.append(wrapper);
  wrapper.setAttribute("style", handlePosition(e));
}

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const specifiedElement = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hover-wrapper]");

  specifiedElement.forEach((p) => {
    let isClickInside = p.contains(event.target);
    if (
      !isClickInside &&
      !event.target.classList.contains("hoverHereToPopUp")
    ) {
      const others = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hover-wrapper]");
      others.forEach((p) => {
        p.style.opacity = 0;
        p.style.transform = "scale(.8)";
        setTimeout(() => {
          p.remove();
        }, 150);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* I minified the css because stackoverflow does not allow to over 30000 character body. this css same with the above snippet.*/

.accordion{background-color:#388070;border:1px;border-bottom:10px;border-color:#f0f0f0;border-radius:3px;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;color:#fff;cursor:pointer;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.2;letter-spacing:2px;padding:12px;outline:0;text-align:left;transition:.4s;width:100%;margin:auto!important}.accordion:hover,.active{background-color:transparent;border:1px;border-color:#388070;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;color:#388070}.accordion:after{content:"\002B";color:#388070;font-size:12px;float:right;margin-left:5px}.active:after{color:#388070;content:"\2212"}.panel5{border:1px;border-bottom:10px;border-color:#f0f0f0;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;padding-top:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:25px;display:none;background-color:#fff;overflow:hidden}.column{float:left;width:25%;font-size:7pt;color:#000;font-family:Lato;font-weight:400;line-height:1.2;background-color:#fff;column-gap:3px}.myrow{float:left;width:100%;font-size:7pt;color:#000;font-family:Lato;font-weight:400;line-height:1.2;background-color:#fff}.myrow:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}a:link,a:visited{background-color:transparent;color:#07342a;display:inline-block;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:12px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none}a:active,a:hover{background-color:transparent;color:#303030;font-weight:700}.jockeys{border-collapse:collapse;display:none;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:12px;width:100%}.jockeys td,.jockeys th{border:1px solid #ddd;padding:8px}.jockeys th{background-color:#07342a;color:#fff;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:12px;text-align:left}.jockeys tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f2f2f2}.ShowJockey:hover+.jockeys{display:block}.hoverPopUp{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:9px;text-align:center;background-color:#fff}.hoverPopUp td,.hoverPopUp th{border:1px solid #ddd;padding:5px}.hoverPopUp th{background-color:#07342a;color:#fff;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:9px;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:1px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;text-align:center}a.hoverHereToPopUp{background-color:#fff;color:#07342a;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:1.2;text-align:left}a:active,a:hover{background-color:transparent;color:red;font-weight:700}table.center{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border-spacing:1}[data-hover-wrapper]{transition:opacity .3s,transform .3s}.parentDiv{line-height:16px;letter-spacing:1px;padding-top:10px;text-align:left}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">NUMBER OF RIDES PER JOCKEY (EXCLUDING SCRATCHINGS)</button>
<div class="panel5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp" data-hover-content="<div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>">click here
              </a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="hoverHereToPopUp" >JAMES INNES JR. HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">KERRIN MCEVOY HAS 6 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp">SAM CLIPPERTON HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">ANDREW ADKINS HAS 1 RIDE.</a><div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey hoverHereToPopUp" data-hover-content="<div class='hoverPopUp'> <table class='center'> <tr> <th>RACECOURSE</th> <th>RACE NO.</th> <th>RUNNER</th> <th>TRAINER</th> <th>TD RATING</th> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 1</td> <td>ROCK AROUND THE CLOCK - ONE (8)</td> <td>DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 2</td> <td>PURE FUEGO - ONE(1)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center> <font color='green'><b>AAA</b></font> </center> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>SANDOWN-HILLSIDE</td> <td>RACE 3</td> <td>ENTREAT - ONE (8)</td> <td>CAMERON CROCKETT</td> <td> <center>AA</center> </td> </tr> </table> </div>">click here</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">NASH RAWILLER HAS 1 RIDE.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TIM CLARK HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">BRENTON AVDULLA HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JASON COLLETT HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">RACHEL KING HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">TOMMY BERRY HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a class="hoverHereToPopUp">GLEN BOSS HAS 2 RIDES.</a>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">JEAN VAN OVERMEIRE (APPRENTICE) HAS 3 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
        <a href="#" class="ShowJockey">ROBBIE DOLAN HAS 4 RIDES.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="parentDiv">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts here. This was an excellent answer and I will probably use it in the future. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Let me revise your requirements,
You will create a table with X rows & Y columns, on hovering any cell you need to show another table right ?

First I would suggest that instead of tables you can go for 'flex' or 'grid' so that DOM will be created in less time than for tables.

Now consider a table with X rows & Y columns, for each cell you can set onmouseover event.
`<td onmouseover=showAssociatedTable(cellId)>`

function showAssociatedTable(cellId) {
//here you can append associated table or
//you can toggle css for associated table with display: 'none' or 'block'
}