# Underscore Template double parent p tag when children contains tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Why does this happen?

I have the following code using underscore templates and jQuery

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

JS

```
const foo = '<div>test</div>';
$('#app').html(_.template('<p><%= foo %></p>'));
```

I expected

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <div>test</div>
  </p>
</div>
```

what I got

```
<div id="app">
  <p></p>
  <div>test</div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Why does the template output 2 sibling `<p>` tags rather than one parent `<p>` tag?

My assumption is Underscore is protecting me from myself from writing code that would be inaccessible, but I don't know if thats really whats happening here.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/brianbest/pen/ExyQwpP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into an instance of a common problem, which is that a `div` tag is not allowed inside a `p` tag.

Generally in HTML, block elements (like `div`) are indeed allowed inside other block elements. But `p` is a special case and it can only contain inline elements (like `span`).

So when the browser encounters the `div` it closes the `p` for you, then renders the div, then creates a new `p` to match your original closing `p`. Hence creating the structure you see in your CodePen.

If you change your code to use:

```
const foo = '<b>test</b>';
```

then it'll work as you expect, because `b` is an inline element and is allowed inside a `p`.

For more info: [Why can't the <p> tag contain a <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it)