# Div inside p messes up Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a `div` with a Sign in with Google button inside. It works fine. But if I put the `div` inside a `p` then Chrome does something weird: instead of putting the `div` inside the `p`, it creates an empty `p` before the `div` and another empty `p` after.

HTML code:

[image: code screenshot]

Elements in Chrome DevTools:

[image: elements screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8397852/15584743) that it's not allowed to do this, so I just won't use a `<p>` tag

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you [edit] your answer to include a link to a source? That will make this answer more useful for future readers.