# Why does my paragraph keep moving after inserting a div into it?

Tags: html, css, dom

I created a fraction using javascript and set the position to static via css. After that i inserted the div in a paragraph via js but the paragraph still moves to the end of the document flow.
How to fix that?

[before inserting div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAtPB.png)
[after inserting div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngTet.png)

my script:

```
            var rlabel = document.getElementById("test")
            
            is_fraction = true
            
            document.getElementById("btndown").disabled = false;
            // generate element instances
            var div1  = document.createElement("div")
            var span1 = document.createElement("span")
            var span2 = document.createElement("span")
            var span3 = document.createElement("span")
             
            div1.setAttribute("id","d1")
            
            //add classes
            div1.classList.add("frac")
            div1.classList.add("relative")
            span2.classList.add("symbol")
            span3.classList.add("bottom")
            
            //create textnodes
            var textspan1 = document.createTextNode("□")
            var textspan2 = document.createTextNode("/")
            var textspan3 = document.createTextNode("□")
            
            //add textnodes
            span1.appendChild(textspan1)
            span2.appendChild(textspan2)
            span3.appendChild(textspan3)

            //add spans
            div1.appendChild(span1)
            div1.appendChild(span2)
            div1.appendChild(span3)
            
            
            
            // add fraction to paragraph
            document.getElementById("test").appendChild(div1)

            //visualize the paragraph
            document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById("test"))
```

my html:

[here is the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAtfx.png)

i also tried it with "relative" but it didnt fixed it.
i thought that the div would appear next to the word called "Rechnung: ".

Comment: There's an important part missing from the code you have given - what is test and what is the overall structure of the HTML? Alsoust to note that you can't put a div element inside a p element 'legally'.

Comment: where is your HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A div as a child of a paragraph is invalid HTML. The browser will tend to fix this by closing your paragraph tag to make the div a sibling

Comment: ok i added my html

Comment: btw thx for the existing comments

Comment: Please don't use images for code. Create a code block and copy-paste the code so that others can easily copy-paste the code and test it for problems.

Comment: Also, [`<p>` cannot contain `<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it)