# Messenger/sms-type styling

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm trying to write some basic HTML to display an SMS or Messenger style output.

For some reason I'm having trouble showing the entries on different rows, with sent messages shown on the right and received on the left, and with an expanding height and width for each message.

For example, this version of the HTML is ok except all messages appear on the left. I appreciate that the "from" divs need to be `position: absolute` really but that causes the rows to overlay, as you might expect.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

div.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div.row {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
}

div.from {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.to {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="from">
      There once was a man from Caracus, who was larking about like a jackass!
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="to">
      Hey!
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="from">
      What's up;
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="to">
      The sky?? :p
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="from">
      Ha ha.
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="to">
      Not much. You?
    </div>
  </div>
  <p />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="from">
      Yeah not much.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I've tried playing around with display and position types, and also differnt elements (the paragraph tags weren't there to start with).

I'm trying to avoid using a table.

Is there a change I can make to the styling to get what I want or am I totally barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: Have you considered flexbox?

Comment: Note that your HTML is somewhat invalid. [`div` is not a valid child of `p`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683474/4665) . Furthermore,  it is good practice to explicitly close your `p` tags.

Comment: @JonP If you look at the HTML closer you'll see that no `div` is a child of a `p`; they are actually siblings. The indenting may make it look like this, but that is the result of an edit someone else made, not me.

Comment: Yet another reason that the `p` tag should be closed, and also a reason to avoid empty elements just for layout. The empty `p` tag adds nothing but confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your HTML greatly. There is no real need for additional containers.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

div.container {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div.row { 
  max-width: 300px;  
  min-width: 150px;
  margin-bottom:2em;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear:both;
}

div.row.from { 
  background-color: blue;
  color: white; 
  float:right;
  
}

div.row.to {  

  float:left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row from">There once was a man from Caracus, who was larking about like a jackass!</div>
    <div class="row to">Hey!</div>
    <div class="row from">What's up;</div>
    <div class="row to">The sky?? :p</div>
    <div class="row from">Ha ha.</div>
    <div class="row  to">Not much. You?</div>
    <div class="row from">Yeah not much.</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes I know, this will certainly be tidied up.

Answer (score 1):

A more modern approach would be to use flexbox.

Set `display: flex` on each row (`flex-direction: row`). Then if you want the text to be at the right, apply `justify-content: flex-end`; or if you want the text on the left, apply `justify-content: flex-start`.

More information on flexbox is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This type of layout scales more gracefully on the modern web, which needs to support many different view ports, devices, etc. And, if you peek at that article, there's a lot more tweaking and adjustments you can do that you simply don't have available using an old-school `float`-based layout.

Here's your full example. Note that I replaced the incorrect `<p>` tags; `<p>` is for text paragraphs, not for forcing whitespace between blocks elements. (It was replaced with a simple `margin-bottom`.)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.from {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.to {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content {
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.from .content {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.to .content {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row from">
    <div class="content">
      There once was a man from Caracus, who was larking about like a jackass!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row to">
    <div class="content">
      Hey!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row from">
    <div class="content">
      What's up;
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row to">
    <div class="content">
      The sky?? :p
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row from ">
    <div class="content">
      Ha ha.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row to">
    <div class="content">
      Not much. You?
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row from">
    <div class="content">
      Yeah not much.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that. Will try to implement that tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Actually just fixed it using `float: right;` and `float: left;`.

I had tried this before but without `clear: both;` which is necessary.

```
div.from {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.to {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]