# how to find all <a>tags under <p> under any level using querySelector javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following html

```
<p>
<div>
<a href='yahoo.com'>go to yahoo</a>
</div>
<p>

<p>
<a href='google.com'>go to google</a>
</p>
```

what path do i pass to querySelectorAll to obtain all a tags that are under p tag at any level.

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working. it is only giving second result.

Comment: Try this: `document.querySelectorAll('p :scope a')`

Comment: <div> is a block level element. <p> should only have inline elements.

Comment: `querySelectorAll("p a")` will work but you can't have `div` as a child of `p`. See: [Why can't the <p> tag contain a <div> tag inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-cant-the-p-tag-contain-a-div-tag-inside-it). Try inspecting the structure of your HTML in the browser dev tools and see if `div` element is nested inside `p` element or not. It won't be. It will be parsed as : `<p></p><div><a>...<a/></div>`

Comment: @AmitMohanty not working

Answer (score 2):

You can get all `<a>` tags under `<p>` tags by using the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) `p a`, this will grab all `<a>` tags that has a `<p>` tag ancestor.

The next problem is your html structure. The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself). Your `<div>` tag is a block-level element use a `<span>` instead of `<div>` then it will show up.

```js
const aTags = document.querySelectorAll('p a');
aTags.forEach((a) => console.log(a.text))
```

```html
<p>
  <span>
    <a href='yahoo.com'>go to yahoo</a>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <a href='google.com'>go to google</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all  tags that are under 



 tags at any level, you can use the **querySelectorAll** method with the CSS selector **p** **a**. This selector will match all  tags that are descendants of any

tag, regardless of the level of nesting.

Here's how you can use it:

```
const allATagsUnderP = document.querySelectorAll('p a');
```

This code will give you a NodeList containing all the  elements that meet your criteria

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Select all <a> tags under <p> elements at any level
const aTagsUnderP = document.querySelectorAll('p a');

aTagsUnderP.forEach((aTag) => {
  console.log(aTag.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all `<a>` tags that are under `<p>` tags at any level, you can use the following CSS selector with `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('p a');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use it:

```
     const allATagsUnderP = document.querySelectorAll('p a');
```

Also there is a problem with your HTML structure.  in a block level element it can't use inside a

tag. You can use  instead of

```
    <p> 

    <span>
    <a href='yahoo.com'>go to yahoo</a>
  </span>
</p>

    <p>
      <a href='google.com'>go to google</a>
    </p>
```

otherwise you can use like this

```
    <p>
  
    <a href='yahoo.com'>go to yahoo</a>
 
</p>

<p>
  <a href='google.com'>go to google</a>
</p>
```