# Dreamweaver html validation issue: "Tag must be paired"

Tags: html, validation, dreamweaver

I'm wondering if this is a quirk in Dreamweaver:
The first tag in my html5 document is:

```
<!doctype html>
```

...and the last tag is:

```
</html>
```

When validating the document (W3C) from within Dreamweaver, I get this error:

> Tag must be paired, no start tag: [ </html> ]

Could it be that Dreamweaver doesn't recognize the first tag with !doctype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!doctype html>` is not an opening-tag. It's an SGML doctytpe declaration.

The `<html>` opening tag goes after it, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Backstory: SGML doctype declarations are usually far more complicated, and when HTML was *ostensibly* an application of SGML (e.g. in HTML4.01) then HTML documents needed full-form SGML DTDs like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

...however, ever since HTML5 was declared as "a living standard" without version numbers, *and* no-longer either SGML nor XML (rip XHTML) there was no need for a HTML5 DTD anymore, but for compatibility purposes the W3C and WHATWG said that `<!doctype html>` (without the older SGML `PUBLIC`/`SYSTEM` parts, and without a URI to the actual DTD) should be used.

See here for details: [Where is the HTML5 Document Type Definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053917/where-is-the-html5-document-type-definition)